# Do we still need the space before the slash in <hr /> and others?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Space Before Closing Slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462741/space-before-closing-slash)

Hi,

If I remember correctly we have it in the first place as some old version of Netscape choked if we didn't add the space (it would think the node never ended).

But is it really necessary today?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462741/space-before-closing-slash

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't valid HTML, with or without the space.

Comment: (except HTML5, as [@Gordon Tucker pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366531/do-we-still-need-the-space-before-the-slash-in-hr-and-others/3366605#3366605)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#syntax-start-tag) specs, [void elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#void-elements) don't need the self closing `/` character.

Their exact phrasing is

> Then, if the element is one of the
>   void elements, or if the element is a
>   foreign element, then there may be a
>   single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/).
>   This character has no effect on void
>   elements, but on foreign elements it
>   marks the start tag as self-closing.

They list void elements as `area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr`

I may be understanding it wrong, but that seems like the following are all valid for html5

```
<hr>
<hr/>
<hr />
```

So it seems it really depends on the doctype you use

Comment: Ah, void elements.. I was thinking about looking it up for a minute, but I got a little lazy and used "and others". Thanks for the knowledge++. :-) And thanks for the other information too of course!

Answer (score 4):

If you're serving valid XML with a correct `content-type: application/xhtml+xml` header, then no. If you're serving [XHTML as HTML](http://www.greytower.net/archive/articles/xhtmlcontent.html), then you [should have it there](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/serving-xhtml-as-html/), though most browsers nowadays can handle some very broken code, so it's only critical if you value having correct markup.

Answer (score 0):

Highly doubt it. Modern browsers are getting quite robust when it comes to things like this.

I've never bothered to insert that extra space myself for quite some time. And frankly, I don't even use XHTML, so I stick to `<br>` without the self closing :)

Comment: boo.  i find if you dont use XHTML then you end up getting burned when you dont expect it.  better to just get in the habit of closing everything.

Comment: For your information, `<hr>`, `<hr/>` and `<hr />` are all valid HTML5.

Comment: @Randy I disagree. While HTML technically allows more untidy code, it doesn't mean I must write untidy code ;) I used to use XHTML because "everyone said it was awesome". However, after a while - most people using it don't even know the *real* difference between it and normal HTML 4.01 strict. And in 99,99% of all cases, XHTML makes no difference at all over well written HTML. Judge the implementation, not the tools used. :)

Comment: @Geert yes I know, but I've just gotten used to writing it without closing it, and I'm fine with that. It does the same job, it validates just as fine and is IMHO cleaner.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.  `<hr/>` doesn't give any validation warning in XHTML, and generalizing about "modern browsers" doesn't provide useful information.