# Why don't empty tags in Ant build files have a space before the closing brace?

Tags: xml, ant, tags, build.xml

A pretty self-explanatory question really, just wondering why empty tags in Ant `build.xml` files always seem to omit the space before the closing `/>`, even though this is a requirement for valid XML 1.0? Perhaps it's a convention that I wouldn't know about since I'm new to Ant, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A space before the closing `/>` isn't a requirement. The following are equivalent:

`<foo/>`

`<foo />`

Some XML editors will actually strip this space when formatting (oXygen in particular).

Comment: Ah, I see, we were always taught that empty tags had to have a space before the closing brace, but I just read the w3c specification for XML after your comment, and indeed, the BNF for this tag is `EmptyElemTag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>'`, so the space was never required. Thanks for that.

Comment: @eZanmoto The space before the slash is an old recommendation for forming XHTML pages in such a way that they were more likely to be successfully parsed by (very) old web browsers that didn't know about XHTML.  I don't know which browsers it actually made a difference with though.

Comment: Here's a question with more details on what Dan Dyer is talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462741/space-before-closing-slash