# XML formatting conventions: Why leave a space before />?

Tags: xml, coding-style, formatting, whitespace

I’ve seen it in several places and e.g. the Eclipse XML auto-formatting does it, too: Put a space before the closing `/>` of an empty element.

Having

```
<element attribute="value"/>
```

would be re-formatted as

```
<element attribute="value" />
```

Why would you do that? From the XML point of view it’s equivalent. Is it a convention? Is it for readability?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Space Before Closing Slash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462741/space-before-closing-slash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is likely done to be safe with XHTML XML, which requires the space in some early XHTML browsers.

Better answer: [Space Before Closing Slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462741/space-before-closing-slash)