# Space after attribute in html5

Tags: html, xhtml

I have heard before that for xhtml, there ought to be a space between any attributes and the closing bracket of a tag. E.g. `<a href="example.com" >` instead of `<a href="example.com">`. Is this true for html5 (and for that matter was it true for xhtml)?

Comment: Similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462741/space-before-closing-slash.  It honestly doesn't matter what you do.

Comment: I assumed it didn't actually matter for any sane browsers, but I was wondering if there was a technically correct choice. And that question isn't exactly what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is not a self-closing tag and *both forms are equivalent, valid syntax* in both HTML (at least 4+) and XML (including XHTML). The similar question linked in the comments is about `/>` constructs, which have historically been "icky".

If a resource said "ought to be", then they are merely talking about a convention as XML (and thus XHTML) doesn't care. Now, self-closing tags can be a different can of worms (that is mostly "fixed" with HTML5 rules), but they are unrelated to this particular syntax construct.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make a difference. Pretty much all browsers will read it correctly. I can't think of any that would read it incorrectly.