# string processing to add trailing slash to self-closing tags (IMG, BR etc)

Tags: javascript, regex

If I get the innerHTML of an element, certain child elements should have a trailing slash to be valid XHTML  (for example, "<br />"), but they don't, in Chrome, Firefox or IE, regardless of the doctype.

Obviously this doesn't matter most of the time, but in my case I am using yanking out html from the DOM as part of a templating system -- so if those backslashes are missing, they go that way into the resulting page built using those templates, and that page won't validate as XHTML because of this. And non-validating pages seem to make my client sad.

So....I'm looking for some javascript code (maybe a regex) that will add that backslash where appropriate.  If it worked for these element types that's good enough for me:

area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, link, meta, param

I guess it has to not get confused if that there is a > in quotes within the tag.

I know there is an dom-to-xml library out there (http://xhtmljs.codeplex.com/) that does this, but it also does a lot of other things and is quite brute force.  I'm hoping for something much simpler.

edit:

All right, since I didn't get any bites on the string processing approach, I went ahead and did something that does the trick for me.  (although it would get confused by a > in quotes, which I'll deal with later):

```
var addClosingSlashes = function (htmlString) {
    var elemTypes = [
    "area", "base", "br", "col", "embed", "hr", "img", "input", "link", "meta", "param"];
    var inString, outString = htmlString;
    for (var i=0; i<elemTypes.length; i++) {
      var index1 = 0, index2;
      inString = outString;
      outString = '';
      while ((index1 = inString.indexOf("<" + elemTypes[i])) != -1) {
        if ((index2 = inString.indexOf(">", index1)) != -1 && inString.substring(index2 - 1, index2 + 1) != '/>') {
          outString += inString.substring(0, index2) + " />";
          inString = inString.substring(index2+1);
          }
        else {
          break;      
          }
        }
      outString += inString;
      }
    return outString;
    };
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm building a page where im pulling in HTMl  from an ajax request, adding it to the DOM and then the user edits bits and pieces via GUI, and then I drop it all to a textarea where they can copy/paste it into salesforce which throws up errors if those self closing slashes aren't present. your little function got me going to exactly where I needed to go (or at least 80% of the way.)

Comment: @SimonJensen Cool good to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is server-side javascript, this won't do anything. By the time the browser executes javascript, the DOM is built as a DOM, and not as some kind of text element. That is, the elements will have been built into a tree already, and there's nothing more you can do to affect rendering.

Comment: Yeah, you probably missed or misunderstood what I'm trying to do.  I have a javascript app that plucks out html from the dom, and uses that for to generate templates in a (php) web app.  So, the trailing slash does matter, in the sense that if it isn't in the innerHTML of elements coming out of my "template doc", it won't be there in the php-generated pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way the source document is served as per the answer in this question: [When objects (e.g. img tag) is created by javascript, it doesn't have the closing tag. How do I make it W3C valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795961/when-objects-e-g-img-tag-is-created-by-javascript-it-doesnt-have-the-closing)

Also, please see the answer of this question... :-) [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks.  Wow, it turns out if I rename it ".xhtml", none of my javascript runs.  Errgh.  Honestly, I'm just doing this to satisfy my client who likes those trailing slashes, and it looks like the only way I'm going to get them in there is with some brute force string processing.

Comment: First run your XHTML through a validator to ensure that it actually is XHTML. Then make sure your JavaScript is referencing elements with an id like: document.getElementById("myID") instead of document.someParentThing.myID

Comment: Thanks John I'll look into that. (I don't do anything like your example though)