# Converting a newline from JS to HTML with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

Supposing that I have an object `data` defined as follows:

```
res.render('index', {
    data: 'Line one\nLine two' });
```

How can I properly render its value in html (by using Jade as template engine) splitting the text on two lines?

**Note:** by using `\<br\>` instead of `\n`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433977/what-about-line-breaks-in-jade

Comment: @myfunkyside—only in XHTML. The OP wants HTML, where it's `<br>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
res.render('index', {
    data: 'Line one <br/> Line two'
})
```

and in index.jade

```
  != data
```