# How to add br tag with Jade HTML

Tags: html, pug

I need add br tag but this not working.

```
table
    tbody
        td Juan Perez
        td 01 33 4455 6677
        td Av José Vasconcelos 804-A Pte. 
            br Col. Los Sabinos,CP. 66220, San Pedro, N.L.
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433977/what-about-line-breaks-in-jade

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What about Line Breaks in Jade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433977/what-about-line-breaks-in-jade)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put the text on a new line with a preceding `|`:

```
table
  tbody
    tr
      td Juan Perez
      td 01 33 4455 6677
      td Av José Vasconcelos 804-A Pte.
        br
        | Col. Los Sabinos,CP. 66220, San Pedro, N.L.
```

You could also place both text nodes on new lines to improve readability as well:

```
table
  tbody
    tr
      td Juan Perez
      td 01 33 4455 6677
      td
        | Av José Vasconcelos 804-A Pte.
        br
        | Col. Los Sabinos,CP. 66220, San Pedro, N.L.
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan Perez</td>
      <td>01 33 4455 6677</td>
      <td>Av José Vasconcelos 804-A Pte.<br/>Col. Los Sabinos,CP. 66220, San Pedro, N.L.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative syntax to the one proposed by Josh is the following:

```
table
  tbody
    tr
      td Juan Perez
      td 01 33 4455 6677
      td. 
        Av José Vasconcelos 804-A Pte. #[br]
        Col. Los Sabinos,CP. 66220, San Pedro, N.L.
```

The dot at the end of the `td` is used to enter large blocks of plain text in a simpler way, so the following indented block is treated as text, and you don't need to use the pipe (`|`) preceding every line. (Source: https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html)

Then, to get your explicit `<br>`, you can use the tag interpolation syntax `#[br]` to inline it inside the text. (Source: https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html)