# Align text in jade?

Tags: html, pug

I have something simple that I'd like to align. Following this answer I saw I could use use `white-space:pre;` https://stackoverflow.com/a/6752736

So I wrote

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
  body
    p.
      Jade is terse

    #Foo
      p(style='white-space:pre;')
        |    One: #[span.A]
        |    Two: #[span.B]
        |  Three: #[span.C]
        |   Four: #[span.D]
        | blah blah blah
```

and got this in my output

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><p>Jade is terse
</p><div id="Foo"><p style="white-space:pre;">   One: <span class="A"></span>   Two: <span class="B"></span> Three: <span class="C"></span>  Four: <span class="D"></span>blah blah blah </p></div></body></html>
```

which completely destroys the point of using `white-space:pre`. I could clean it up by hand (see blow) but then there isn't a point to using jade. I don't use HTML or jade much. Whats the best way to fix this? Using a table? (If so how) use a ul?

```
<p style="white-space:pre;">
   One: <span class="A"></span>
   Two: <span class="B"></span>
 Three: <span class="C"></span>
  Four: <span class="D"></span>
  blah blah blah </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, `white-space:pre;` and piping can only preserve the formatting if there are no nested tags (i.e. your `span`s). To get the output to print exactly as you might like with piping and inline tags, you have to get a little hacky and use some manner of escaped character string interpolation (`#{}`) that renders inline JavaScript.

The basic interpolation expression you'll need somewhere is `#{'\n\t\t'}` to ensure it lines up with the tag. As with regular JavaScript, `\n` will return the string to the beginning of the next line, hence the need for `\t`s.

There are a variety of ways you can implement this interpolation, however.

#### Inline

```
p(style='white-space:pre;')
  |#{'\n\t\t'}    One: #[span.A]
  |#{'\n\t\t'}    Two: #[span.B]
  |#{'\n\t\t'}  Three: #[span.C]
  |#{'\n\t\t'}   Four: #[span.D]
  |#{'\n\t\t'} blah blah blah
```

In your example, all of the colons prefacing the `span` are indented 8 characters, so you can line them up using some simple math and `.repeat` without having to figure out the particulars of how many spaces to have.

#### Function

Note the `-` in front of the function, which is necessary to run a line of JavaScript.

```
-function whiteSpaceFunc(str) { return '\n\t' + ' '.repeat(8-str.length) + str + ': ';}

p(style='white-space:pre;')
  |#{whiteSpaceFunc('One')}#[span.A]
  |#{whiteSpaceFunc('Two')}#[span.B]
  |#{whiteSpaceFunc('Three')}#[span.C]
  |#{whiteSpaceFunc('Four')}#[span.D]
  |#{'\n\t\t'}  blah blah blah
```

#### Mixin

A more native approach of functions. Note the use of `className` rather than `class` as a parameter; `class` seems to be reserved and throws an error.

```
   p(style='white-space:pre;')
        mixin whiteSpacedLine(str,className)
          |  #{'\n\t\t' + ' '.repeat(8-str.length)}#{str}: #[span(class=className)]
      +whiteSpaceLine('One','A')
      +whiteSpaceLine('Two','B')
      +whiteSpaceLine('Three','C')
      +whiteSpaceLine('Four','D')
```

#### Mixin + Iteration

Perhaps the most simple way to do this. If you spread the `vals` array across multiple lines as in the code below, make sure to wrap them inside a code block indented under a `-`, and ensure the `-` does not have any space afterward. (You could, of course, contain it to one line.)

```
  p(style='white-space:pre;')
            mixin whiteSpacedLine(str,className)
              |  #{'\n\t\t' + ' '.repeat(8-str.length)}#{str}: #[span(class=className)]
            -
              var vals = [
                     {char: 'A', num: 'One'},
                     {char: 'B', num: 'Two'},
                     {char: 'C', num: 'Three'},
                     {char: 'D', num: 'Four'}
                     ];
            - each item in vals
              +whiteSpacedLine(item.num,item.char)
            |#{'\n\t\t'} blah blah blah
```