# How to use <br> in pug file?

Tags: html, node.js, express

Desired HTML:

```
<br/>
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
```

My Pug code was:

```
br 
  form#contact-form(method='post'action='contact.php' role='form')
```

But it's showing the error:

> br is a self closing element: `<br/>` but contains nested content.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433977/what-about-line-breaks-in-jade

Answer (score 3):

If your code is located inside a div, your pug template would have to look like this:

```
div
   br
   form#contact-form(method='post'action='contact.php' role='form')
```

From the [pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag)

Remember:

`</br>` isn't valid, because it's a self closing element.

`<br/>` and `<br>` are valid.

[Source (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

Answer (score 0):

Indenting the `form` underneath the `br` like you have in your code—

```
// incorrect
br
  form
```

—tells Pug you're trying to create this HTML—

```
<br><form></form></br>
```

—which is invalid because line-break elements can't contain other elements.

Instead, place the line-break *at the same indentation level* the form, which tells Pug they should be siblings, like this—

```
// correct
br
form
```

—which will compile to:

```
<br>
<form></form>
```