# html convention - self-close tag, > or />, in other way <br> or <br/>

Tags: html, coding-style

When take some tutorial from web, I see many people leaves tags open like `<link ..>`, `<img ..>`. But when I use Netbeans to edit them (the HTML/JSP pages), it show a red background on those tags until I add the slash into them.  `<br>` --> `<br/>`.

Which is the correct way to write HTML-based code?

Comment: I've done many search by GOOGLE, BING ... but got none helpful thing.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are fine for HTML. Though not for XHTML which is an XML dialect.

Some elements do not need a closing (`/>`) tag - in particular empty elements (those that do not have content). Examples are `<hr>` and `<br>`. These *can* also be self closing (`<hr />` and `<br />`, respectively). This self closing is equivalent to having a close tag immediately after the open tag.

For XML, such a non closing tag is not valid - it must be closed, either self closing or have a closing tag. So `<hr>` is not valid XML, but `<hr />` and `<hr></hr>` are.

HTML is not XML, but for better compatibility some tools try to emit as much XML like HTML as possible.

Comment: As per your deleted "@Downvoter, care to explain?" comment, I downvoted because the original answer was wrong and not useful. Apparently you've posted it in all hurry. Now it's a bit more reasonable after you fixed it and added 3 paragraphs to reiterate Chris. I removed the downvote.

Comment: @BalusC - Fair enough. I do tend to post a quick answer and then add detail to it, flesh it out and fix any inaccuracies.

Comment: Good answer, upvoted. May want to note, though, that `<div />` is not the same as `<div></div>` in HTML doctypes; browsers may misread it as just `<div>`, breaking the document.

Answer (score 5):

It depends which [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) you're using.  If you're using HTML 4 then you shouldn't use self-closing tags, if XHTML then you should to make valid XML, and if HTML 5 then closing slashes are optional, but not required.

The [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org) will throw a warning if you try to use closing tags in HTML 4:

> The sequence  can be
>   interpreted in at least two different
>   ways, depending on the DOCTYPE of the
>   document. For HTML 4.01 Strict, the
>   '/' terminates the tag '). However, since many
>   browsers don't interpret it this way,
>   even in the presence of an HTML 4.01
>   Strict DOCTYPE, it is best to avoid it
>   completely in pure HTML documents and
>   reserve its use solely for those
>   written in XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

`>` is correct for `HTML`, but incorrect for `XHTML`. Check your DOCTYPE.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

for `HTML strict`
and

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

for `XHTML strict`