# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined and init completed is run

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatable.net. I get this error even though th and td column numbers are equal. "Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'nTf' of undefined"

only 1 input does not give this error. I get the same error when I add it to other output. And datatable ajax does not work when all inputs are available.

And init completed is not running.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  $("#gelenBasvurularim").attr("style", "width: 100%;border: #dddddd solid 1px !important;");
});
var tabLes = $('#gelenBasvurularim').DataTable({
  "bServerSide": true,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "ordering": true,
  "sorting": [
    [0, 'asc']
  ],
  "pageLength": 10,
  "responsive": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "/IncomingApplications/OnayListele",
  "language": {
    "url": "/assets/datatable/tr.json"
  },
  "columnDefs": [{
    visible: true
  }],
  "LengthMenu": [
    [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 9999999],
    [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 'Tümünü Göster']
  ],
  "select": "single",
  "dom": 'lBfrtip',
  "lengthChange": true,
  "columns": [{
    "data": "BildirimTuruMetni"
  }],
  "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
    alert("draw call back " + oSettings);
    $("#bildirimTables").attr("style", "width: 100%;");

  },
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    alert(1);
    $("tfoot tr").appendTo("thead");

    $('.search-input-text').on('keyup click',
      function() {
        console.log("input text");
        var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
        alert(i);
        var v = $(this).val();
        alert(v);
        $('#gelenBasvurularim').DataTable().columns(i).search(v).draw();

      });

    $('.search-input-select').on('change',
      function() {
        var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
        var v = $(this).val();
        $('#gelenBasvurularim').DataTable().columns(i).search(v).draw();
      });

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="gelenBasvurularim" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>İsim</th>
      <th>Soyisim</th>
      <th>Birim Adı</th>
      <th>Oluşturma Tarihi</th>
      <th>Talep Türü Adı</th>
      <th>Talep Durumu Adı</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" data-column="0" class="search-input-text form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-column="1" class="search-input-text form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-column="2" class="search-input-text form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-column="3" class="search-input-text form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-column="4" class="search-input-text form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-column="5" class="search-input-text form-control"></td>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: you're not closing your inputs...try to close them.

Comment: @ElmerDantas -- `input` is a self-closing tag. You don't need `</input>` or even use `/>` at the end of it.

Comment: ı closed inputs but it did not improve

Comment: @31piy I know but does the framework he's using know this? He has the same number on header and footer the only thing that seems "irregular" for me are the inputs...so, that's why I commented.

Comment: @ElmerDantas reread 31piy's comment. You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079746/html-convention-self-close-tag-or-in-other-way-br-or-br) leave `input` "opened" like this, whatever the framework he is using.

Comment: Also, @yuksel you should check the options you are giving to `DataTable`, because removing all of them makes it work.