# Extract URL until whitespace or <br> tag using Regex with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like:

```
Webcam recording https://www.example.com/?id=456&code=123
```

or like:

```
Webcam recording https://www.example.com/?id=456&code=123<br><b>test<b>
```

To extract the URL from the first example I used: `var reg_exUrl = /\bhttps?:\/\/[^ ]+/g;`

Now I tried to extend the Regex so it takes the first match until whitespace (end of line) **or** `<br>` tag.

This was my attempt:

```
var reg_exUrl = /\b(https?:\/\/[^ ]+)(\<br\>)/g;
```

Which looks good on https://regex101.com/r/gudNab/1 and shows up as two different matches.

But using the Regex in Javascript, the `<br>` tag gets always included in the link.

Using `var matches = line.match(reg_exUrl);` gives me with `matches[0]`:

```
https://www.example.com/?id=456&code=123<br>
```

instead of the desired `https://www.example.com/?id=456&code=123`

Comment: A br can also have self closing slash also `<br/>`. If doing this in browser using dom prser to extrct just the text is easy

Comment: Your comment is unrelated to the question and even wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6079746/1066234

Comment: Not entirely wrong and you may need to account for both. Let dom parser do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select text before the `<br>` you can use a postive lookahead.
`https?:\/\/.*?(?=<br>)`

Adding in a `$` and `\n` for an early end of input: `https?:\/\/.*?(?=<br>|$|\n)`

```js
const regexp = /https?:\/\/.*?(?=<br>|$|\n)/;
const testString = "Webcam-Aufnahme https://www.example.com/file?id=959559110184937375.mp4&code=4yrn1ev<br>**test**";

console.log(testString.match(regexp)[0])
```

See on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dQNtIZ/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just learned that `?=` is the positive lookahead.  I am using now `var reg_exUrl = /\b(https?:\/\/[^ ]+)(?=<br>)/g;`

Comment: @Avatar great, but keep in mind that your regex wil fail if there is more than one instance of `<br>` in the string. Use the lazy modifier `?` in order to stop before the first `<br>`: --- `\b(https?:\/\/[^ ]+?)(?=<br>)`

Comment: Could maybe use `$` -- `\b(https?:\/\/[^ ]+?)(?=<br>|$)`

Comment: Thanks. I just see that the Regex does not match the first string example anymore: Nice to see here: https://regex101.com/r/yKin9E/1 - I need both examples to be matched. – `\b(https?:\/\/[^ ]+?)(?=<br>|$)` works now! https://regex101.com/r/BzrkFa/1 – What is the `|$` doing. Is it kind of "or"?

Comment: Yes, `|` means or, and `$` means the end of the string --- `<br>|$` means either a <br> or the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

You get the full match as you are using `matches[0]` but you have 2 capture groups where the part without the `<br>` is in capture group 1.

You can get that group value using match if you remove the global `/g` flag.

```js
var line = "Webcam recording https://www.example.com/?id=456&code=123<br><b>test<b>\n";
var reg_exUrl = /\b(https?:\/\/[^ ]+)(\<br\>)/;
var matches = line.match(reg_exUrl);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

If you want both examples to match, you can use a pattern without a non greedy quantifier by using a negated character class that matches any char except `<`, and only matches it if it is not directly followed by `br>`

The pattern matches:

- `\bhttps?:\/\/`
- `[^\s<]*` Optionally match any char except a whitespace char or `<`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `<(?!br>)` Match `<` if not directly followed by `br>`
  - `[^\s<]*` Optionally match any char except a whitespace char or `<`
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat

```js
const regex = /\bhttps?:\/\/[^\s<]*(?:<(?!br>)[^\s<]*)*/;
[
  "Webcam-Aufnahme https://www.example.com/file?id=959559110184937375.mp4&code=4yrn1ev<br><b>test<b><br>",
  "Webcam-Aufnahme https://www.example.com/file?id=959559110184937375.mp4&code=4yrn1ev"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[0]);
  }
});
```