# Permanently change HTML element

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, element

I'm browsing a website a few time a day, and one button is disabled, I have to manually enable it from developer menu / Element

```
<div class="actioning-buttons">
  <button class="action-button one-action-button" disabled="">Number 1</button> 
</div>
```

Can I automatically have this enabled for this database / website without having to do a manual edit all the time?

PS Im using Google Chrome for OSX

Comment: A userscript is the way to go: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a simple [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) to achieve this. When you trigger the bookmark, your browser will run the code in the context of the current page. I know this isn't really automating the process but since you don't have a fixed URL for the page, this will probably have to do. It's definitely an improvement over opening your developer tools each time and manually editing the code.

Here's a bookmarklet that, when run, will look for all `button`s with the classes `action-button` and `one-action-button`, then remove the `disabled` attribute.

```
javascript:Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('action-button one-action-button')).forEach(function(v){v.removeAttribute("disabled");});
```

Just add a new bookmark, type the above code as is in the URL/location field and save it some place handy. Click on it each time you want to remove the disabled attribute.

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Wow, that's perfect, exactly what wanted, thank you so much @Daksh Shah

Comment: Glad I could be of help mate! :)

Answer (score 4):

That is the Job of a userscript manager.

A userscript manager does the task of injecting scripts defined by user to sites they visit automatically.

For Firefox, [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) is there and for Chrome, [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) is there

After you install the extension, do the steps

- Go to the site where you want it to work
- click on the icon and choose **Create new script**
  [image]
- It will give a page like this

[image]

- Enter the script and save it.

Comment: Ah shoot! You beat me to it! Worthy post to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686070/changing-html-with-greasemonkey

Comment: Thank for the reply, unfortunately Tampermonkey redirect me to the Google Chrome download page, I guess it's not compatible with OSX. I'll try to found a another userscript Manager

Comment: @KevinCork looks weird. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/X0rBvBWoVjc

Comment: PS the URL address of the page I want to change have a dynamic encrypted text (which mean that the full URL is never the same)

Comment: then it will be difficult. Do you have any problem in disclosing the url? If not, please give me the url