# Is it not necessary to close the tag in HTML 5 like HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c

Is it not necessary to close the tag in HTML 5 like HTML? or it's a bug in W3C validator

Why this code is valid in W3C validator

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<p>Some Text
  </body>
</html>
```

I would be surprised if it's really valid in HTML5. But is there any benefit to keep this behavior valid in HTML5. Do HTML5 creators think that stricter rules of XHTML were not good for Web?

Comment: Are you sure that it passed the W3X validator? Tags do need to be closed.

Comment: Similar question already asked.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Comment: "Do HTML5 creators think that stricter rules of XHTML were not good for Web?" You're kidding, right? Most people don't *read* and can't even **spell**, much less follow extremely precise documentation.

Comment: Ummm, close what tag? The `<p>` tag?

Comment: @BoltClock - Yes the `<p>` tag

Comment: The `</body>` and `</html>` tags are not necessary either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That markup is indeed valid. [`<p>` tags don't have to be closed in HTML 4.01 or HTML5.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) I'm not sure where you got the idea that HTML5 requires everything to be closed like in XHTML.

HTML5 is just regular HTML with extra new features (hence the version jump from 4.01 to 5). It does not in any way derive from XHTML. You **can** close all of your HTML5 tags so it looks like well-formed XML, but the spec doesn't **require** you to.

Comment: I just thougt it would be invalid in HTML5. but if it is a part of specification in HTML 4.01 and HTML 5. why they didn't changed in HTML5. I don't think if is there any benefit of not closing the tag. I just think some of good things of XHTML should have adopted in HTML 5

Comment: Then what's the benefit of requiring a closing `</p>` tag?

Comment: Then is it also ok to not to close html, head, and body?

Comment: But this code is also valid in w3c validator http://chopapp.com/#42j7l4wt I removed closing tags for head, body and html

Comment: Oh then that's my mistake. If you need to know whether a tag needs to be closed, refer to the spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup

Comment: @BoltClock The benefit would be for organization within your text editor (collapsible elements)

Answer (score 7):

> Do HTML5 creators think that stricter rules of XHTML were not good for
>   Web?

Pretty much, yes.

Their view is that it just makes creating a web page harder. HTML has been wildly successful because just about anyone can create a working web page without knowing barely any HTML at all. It's a very small learning curve to get started which people can build upon when they're ready.

If you need to know a lot of pedantic rules just to get started, then many people won't bother, and HTML will not be as successful.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the closing tag for a `<p>` element out is valid in most situations, though there are a few where it isn't. The [exact rules at the World Wide Web Consortium](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) are:

> A **p** element’s end tag may be omitted if the **p** element is immediately followed by an [address](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/address.html#address), [article](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/article.html#article), [aside](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/aside.html#aside), [blockquote](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/blockquote.html#blockquote), dir, [div](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html#div), [dl](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html#dl), [fieldset](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/fieldset.html#fieldset), [footer](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/footer.html#footer), [form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/form.html#form), [h1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html#h1), [h2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h2.html#h2), [h3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h3.html#h3), [h4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h4.html#h4), [h5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h5.html#h5), [h6](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h6.html#h6), [header](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html#header), [hr](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hr.html#hr), [menu](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/menu.html#menu), [nav](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/nav.html#nav), [ol](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html#ol), p, [pre](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/pre.html#pre), [section](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/section.html#section), [table](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table), or [ul](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul) element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an [a](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a) element.

So, for example, the following is invalid:

```
<a href="http://example.com><p>This paragraph is unclosed</a>
```

But this is valid:

```
<div class="news"><p>Something important happened!</div>
```

HTML never required the `<p>` tag to be closed—it was always optional. You *may* close your HTML tags so it looks like well-formed XHTML, but that isn't necessary. XHTML is more strict than HTML.