# Why doesn't <br> get added to the error messages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, function

I am validating a form and I am showing a message in a popup window,  But `<br>`  doesnt get after the error message. Why is it so. My code is as follow:

```
function closeBox() {
            var errorMsg = "";
                var ferrorMsg =  "first name is needed" + "<br>";
                var aerrorMsg = "Please type address" + "<br>";
                var eerrorMsg = "Please type a valid email Address"
                if($("#name").val() == "") {
                    errorMsg += ferrorMsg;
                }
                if($("#address").val() == "") {
                    errorMsg += aerrorMsg;
                }
                if($("#email").val() == "") {
                    errorMsg += eerrorMsg;
                }

                $(".errorContainer").text(errorMsg);


                $(".popupBox").remove();
                }


$("body").append("<div class='overlay'><div class='errorContainer'></div><div><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='closeBox()'>X</a><div></div>");
```

Comment: MДΓΓ БДLL has the answer, also I would suggest `<br />` in place of `<br>`

Comment: @Jashwant why would you do that? (just curious)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Sorry, I am a victim of w3schools again :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2), when you should be using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

Answer (score 0):

use $(".errorContainer").**html**(errorMsg); instead $(".errorContainer").**text**(errorMsg);

Comment: this question has already been answered in that respect do you know how do i acheeive what is in the comment to david