# Getting innerHTML contains extra <br> tag, is this normal?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, innerhtml, contenteditable

When I create a new element and I start typing (with the contentEditable set to true), and then look at it's innerHTML, it always contains an extra `<br>` at the end. If I look at the innerHTML before typing, I am getting the correct value. Is this normal? My problem is that I'm counting the number of lines using the `<br>` tag, and I can't have it give me more than I need. Here is some test code (javascript):

```
var _this = this;
function keyup(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 112)
    {
        alert(_this.code.innerHTML);
    }
}
function create()
{
    this.code = document.createElement("div")
    this.code.innerHTML = "Hello world.<br>I like testing popcorn.<br>Testing again.";
    this.code.contentEditable = "true";
    this.code.onkeyup = keyup;
    document.body.appendChild(this.code);
    _this = this;
}
window.onload = function()
{
    create();
}
```

The code is set up so when you press F1, it shows the contents of div. I am using the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: Could you please post the code where you're updating the innerHtml as well?

Comment: Just run the test code, you can update the innerHTML by typing anything into the div.

Answer (score -1):

First off, that tag should be `<br />`  not `<br>`, secondly a div is a block element and while you shouldn't see a `<br>` tag, you will see a new line after the div is created.

If you output the innerHTML value of that div element after it is created, what is the output?

Comment: First of all, </br> does not validate with the W3 validator. When I output the innerHTML after it is created, I get the same thing that I input into it, without the ending <br>. In terms of my test code: "Hello world.<br>I like testing popcorn.<br>Testing again." What you're saying does make sense though, but I still need to find somewhat of a solution...

Comment: Let's not discuss <br/> vs <br>. <br> is fine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Comment: EiJay—you are mistaken. The markup `<br/>` is for XHTML (which does not allow unclosed tags), it is a syntax error in HTML that is tolerated by browsers. The vast majority of XHTML documents on the web are served as HTML, so HTML markup is fine (and generally preferred since many browsers can't handle XML on the web.

Comment: It all depends on whether the page is declared with type html (probably not) or type xhtml (more likely).

Comment: @ElJay: It's a lot less likely than it was a few years ago. There are very few reasons to create a new web page in XHTML now, and as RobG points out, IE < 9 never supported XHTML in the first place.