# linq to entity query returns list as continuous string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var ChangesOthersResult = surveyResponseRepository.Query.Select(r => r.ChangesOthers);
```

That returns all of the entries in "ChangesOthers" column from my table.

When I return the data inside my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ChangesOthersResult)
```

It is returning all of the data as a single continous string of text.  How can I add a line break in between the columns of data that it is returning?

```
  var data = new ResultsViewModel() 
                        {
                            PatientFollowUpResult = PatientFollowUpResult,
                            PatientFollowUpResultPct = PatientFollowUpResultPct,

                            TotalResponsesResult = TotalResponsesResult,

                            ChangesOthersResult = ChangesOthersResult,

                        };
```

View Model Type

```
@model CMESurvey.ViewModels.ResultsViewModel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
@foreach (var x in Model.ChangesOthersResult)
{
   @x<br>
}
```

Comment: Use <br /> instead of <br> :)

Comment: @JK. not in HTML5 :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            HeaderName1
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modeItem.FieldName)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I get an error saying "does not contain a definition for GetEnumerator" if I use a ForEach loop.

Comment: @user547794 Then you're not pasting the model to the view AsEnumerable. Can you post the code that passes this to your view?

Answer (score 0):

Razor doesn't know that you want line breaks in between each item when you use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ChangesOthersResult)
```

You can literally add the line break in the select by adding the string `"<br/>"` to each item before selecting it:

```
var ChangesOthersResult = surveyResponseRepository
                             .Query
                             .Select(r => r.ChangesOthers + "<br />");
```

Comment: I tried this but it's sending the literal text "<br />" (&lt;br /&gt;)