# Replace "Environment.NewLine" inside a <div class="text"> with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was asking myself if it possible to replace all the Environment.NewLine in a specific div with Regex? I tried some regex by myself but I didn't succeed in it. By the way, I know it's not the right way to parse HTML with Regex.

This is what I had so far:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=<div class=""text"">.*?)" + Environment.NewLine + "(?=.*?</div>)", "<br/>");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(text, 
  @"(?<=<div class=""text"">.*?)((?<!\n)\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)(?=.*?</div>)", 
  "<br>");
```

Comment: `<br>` vs `<br />` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Answer (score 2):

```
... + Regex.Escape(Environment.NewLine) + ...
```