# CSS hide plain text with no surrounding HTML?

Tags: html, css

Need to hide text behind a `<br>`..

Here is what is there in the HTML & CSS: [JsFiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/kamodev/42bNm/)

Yes, the `<br>` tag does not have anything in and does not hold content

Comment: Why not just wrap the text in a `<span>` and put a class or ID on the span?

Comment: A `<br />` tag cannot contain any content. It's a simple break and that's all.

Comment: `<br>` should be `<br />` as it is an opening and closing tag all in one, therefore as someone else mentioned it cannot contain anything.

Comment: The content is being generated via libraries and to hard to change

Comment: text nodes cannot be styled via css. you'll have to wrap the text in a span or other tag and hide that new node.

Comment: @JonTaylor That's XHTML. It's [perfectly fine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1946446/492405) for plain HTML. In fact, [for HTML5 it can be wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/492405).

Comment: @MarcB could you not style all text on the page to be hidden then make sure you set an explicit style on all other tags to make it visible again?  This would technically allow you to style text that isnt in a tag.

Comment: @jon: that'd be highly painful, especially if there's other hidden/visible text elsewhere on the page. it'd be a highly ugly game of whack-a-mole.

Comment: @MarcB yeah I agree, just throwing it out there that technically it would be possible.

Comment: You could change the page content with Javascript, looking for the text between the <br> tags.  I don't see where it's possible with straight CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to grab the node at runtime and wrap it in a hidden span.
http://jsfiddle.net/XrPuU/2

Not extremely flexible or dynamic, but if you can't control the output to begin with your options are pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap with a div and make a class that has the visibility: hidden attribute?

```
.noshow { visibility: hidden;}

<div class="noshow">Some text to hide</div>
```

Comment: because he said the code is generated and thus too hard to change.

Comment: That comment by him was added while I was typing my response so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with :after pseudo selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: That selector, I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: this won't work with dynamic content since he'd have to 'dynamically' create the class with the content: being populated with what he wants to hide.