# Line breaks are not working

Tags: html, page-break

My page has `<p></p>` but it still does not have breaks. Any clue? [links is here](http://www.iurecsports.org/node/181)

Comment: Page looks great to me. Where are you having problems?

Comment: It has been solved, thanks to everyone

Answer (score 3):

`<p>` is a paragraph not a line-break. The line break tag is `<br>`

Comment: @Nile I have no idea what you're talking about :P

Comment: @adatapost please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946446/1057429)

Answer (score 3):

In the event you were talking about line breaks that element you want is `<br />` and yes the space is required, this is the best way to get a webbrowser to behave when using line breaks, because it complies to XML as well (self-contained tag).

If you mean you wanted more space around your paragraph use CSS to change the style for the 'p' element.

Comment: Here's a [*good read*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br)

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I forgot to mention you should use XHTML to "guarantee" browser compatability.

Comment: That is an interesting point, which is why garentee is in quotes, I can just say how it is supposed to work ( and it does work fine for me all the time,). If the browser manufacturers want botch the interpretation (looking at you microsoft), and the sysadmin is going to misconfigure the webserver, that's to bad.  However failing to comply with the standard isn't going to mprove the situation.  And users gravitate away from web browsers that don't properly dispaly pages.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wikimedia_browser_share_pie_chart_3.png

Comment: My point was that `Very few people actually use XHTML` not that using it will not work with IE (which also supports using `<br>` over `<br />`).

Comment: Just because lots of people don't doesn't mean lots of people shouldn't. Many people opted to smoke over not smoking, that didn't make it a good idea, if you are having formatting issues a strict interpreter is the best kind of medicine.

Comment: That's like saying that people should drive 20mph cause there'll be less car accidents. The problem is that they won't be able to get anywhere... ;)

Comment: No it's like saying driving way over the speed limit may be benificial in the short run, but a pain in the long run. But sure this cooment section is getting to long, it'd not a forum.

Answer (score 2):

In your global.css, the first line reads:

```
p,caption { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-weight:inherit; font-style:inherit; font-size:100%; font-family:inherit; vertical-align:baseline; }
```

That is telling it not to give your paragraphs any spacing above or below.

So you need to go into http://www.iurecsports.org/pw_files/css/global.css and edit it like so:

```
caption { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-weight:inherit; font-style:inherit; font-size:100%; font-family:inherit; vertical-align:baseline; }

p { margin:ENTER VALUE; padding:ENTER VALUE; border:0; outline:0; font-weight:inherit; font-style:inherit; font-size:100%; font-family:inherit; vertical-align:baseline; }
```

Keep in mind that if you set margin to `margin:10px` and padding to `padding:10px` (for example) your paragraphs will have 10px top, bottom, left, and right margins and padding.

To JUST give it top & bottom margins / padding, set to something like `margin:10px 0` and `padding:10px 0`.

You'll probably need to play around w/ it to get it looking just the way you want it.

Cheers!