# What is the difference between this html5 form elements?

Tags: html

I am learning HTML5, i want to know why these elements are closed differently the first input ends with > and the second ends with /> what difference does it make?

```
<input name = "howtosite" type = "radio"
              value = "search engine" checked>
```

---

```
<input type = "color" autofocus /> 
              (Hexadecimal code such as #ADD8E6)
```

Comment: Input tags are self-closing, so the two are identical. It's like `<br>` vs `<br />`.

Comment: @Blender: Void, not self-closing. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, some terminology: Confusingly, "HTML" now means two things:

- The definition of the various kinds of elements that make up what we use in web pages and such. This is what tells us that there is an element called `div` and what it's for.
- One of the two *serializations* of it (the written form), which tells us we write `div` elements like this: `<div>content</div>`.

The other serialization of HTML is XHTML. The two serializations differ in places, because XHTML is XML.

HTML defines some elements that never have content, like `<br>`, and in the HTML serialization they're usually written just like that, `<br>`. In the XHTML serialization that's a problem, because XML requires that all tags be closed and `<br>` is just a start tag. Putting the slash ("solidus") just before the ending `>` closes the tag, so in XHTML, `<br>` becomes `<br/>`. The `/` is *tolerated* in the HTML serialization, but it serves no purpose. It only serves a purpose in XHTML. (Note that in really, really old browsers, you may need a space before the solidus, e.g. `<br />`, but we're talking very old indeed.)

This is **only true** for [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) like `<br>` and `<input>` that never have any content, and [foreign elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#foreign-elements) (MathML and SVG). You never write `<div/>`, for instance, even if the `div` is going to be empty. The correct form of an empty `div` is always `<div></div>` (whether in the HTML or XHTML serialization).

Full detail in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), and in particular [§8.1.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags).

So regarding your two specific examples: The first is only valid in the HTML serialization. The second is also valid in the HTML serialization, and would be valid in the XHTML serialization if the `autofocus` attribute had a value (in XML, attributes must have a value, so you have to write `autofocus="autofocus"`).

Comment: It's important to say that in HTML 5, it doesn't matter either way, as both are valid.

Comment: Using or not using the solidus

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I think it's only NS5/IE4 (or some other extreme legacy/fringe) browsers that didn't accept `<br/>` as `<br>`. I usually see `<br />` as [the "compatible" way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br) to write it under HTML 4 / XHTML, though. (Writing `<br></br>` is a *different* issue.)

Comment: Since the question is regarding HTML 5, I can safely argue this isn't an issue

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Then why bring up HTML5 (or not) at all? :p

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: It *does* matter if you're using the XHTML serialization of HTML5. In the HTML serialization of HTML5, I believe I covered it: *"The `/` is tolerated in HTML, but it serves no purpose. It only serves a purpose in XHTML."* :-)

Comment: thanks, I have to find out what you are talking about with Serialization I heard of the term in Java only. thanks anyway

Comment: @RuruMorlano: It's a similar concept, but basically, in this context it just means "How you write it down." :-) HTML defines a `br` element (line break); the HTML serialization of a `br` element is `<br>` (e.g., that's how you write it in an HTML file); the XHTML serialization of a `br` element is `<br/>` (that's how you write it in an XHTML file).

Comment: @RuruMorlano: Hope that helped.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah of course it helped. I didn't know that. I just jump to what matters for now, thanks tho...I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @RuruMorlano: No worries, I could see you were new here, as we all were once. :-) Best,