# <br> not causing new line on Chrome

Tags: html, css

[**Example page**](http://jsbin.com/ezatoy/1/edit)

[image]

I have some `<span>` elements which are `inline-block` and after the last `<span>` I have a `<br>` to break a new line (could be more than just one `<br>`).

The new line works on *Firefox* but doesn't work on *Chrome* (v. 24). Don't know why.

I write this so people who are searching the internet would have something to read regarding this matter, because I did not find anything on google/stackoverflow regarding this.

Comment: What is the `line-height` property for your page?

Comment: you can see the demo page

Comment: What's the goal here? Using a `<br />` this way seems hacky.

Comment: its the semantic way for breaking a line. I need a new line when the user pressed the "enter" key in my plugin.

Comment: wtf is this? why is this very important question, which has no answer on the internet, is voted down? there are people out there who might be looking for a fix at every given every moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: http://jsbin.com/ezatoy/32/edit

By adding a [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) to the container element like so:

```
div:after{ content:'\0200B'; }
```

This insures that there will be some content after the last `<br>` occurrence, effectively breaking into a new line. no need to add/change any DOM.

Answer (score 2):

as soon as u add content, it works. chrome just doesn't like giving you empty space.

try adding `&nbsp;` on the empty new line.

Edit: changing since there was so much discussion on the topic.

Firefox has a bug, it should not display the newline. According to W3C standards the element "[must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/br)". Without content following the `<br>`, it will not create this newline.

Comment: i know as soon as i add content it will work. in my case i cannot add content. I just want to understand if this is a bug or normal behavior. this is for a very complex jquery plugin I'm creating, and this is a simplified demo of my problem.

Comment: i am looking for a clean way to solve this via CSS without adding DOM

Comment: looks like Firefox has the bug. it doesn't do a new line in Opera or IE either

Comment: normally Firefox is in-line with W3C and chrome is behind, so I wouldn't count on that. and Opera is very very shitty browser in terms of W3C support..

Comment: please lets not start a browser war. the point is that what u are looking for only works on Firefox. and the bigger point is that you should test all possible browser-specific problems on all browsers.

Comment: well, in my specific case I only care about Chrome and Firefox, and this is just insane, i mean, if you put a <br> you would expect it to break a new line. but it doesn't..now I can't just call the Chrome team and ask them, why this doesn't work..I'm stuck at just not understanding the reason, and i didn't find any info on this on the internet..

Comment: ur still attributing Chrome with the problem, when literally all browsers other than Firefox display the same behavior. i don't know what else to tell u other than there are many roads to the same place, so find a different one. and while ur at it, perhaps u should follow the W3C standard of <br /> rather than <br>, as u recognize the value of these standards.

Comment: <br> is the way, not <br />, which is XHTML. you can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1946446/104380

Comment: ah, i stand corrected, my mistake. now, back to u stopping the complaints about something you can't change, and moving on.

Comment: your answer and attitude do not help this issue at hand. everything is solvable, and what is not, must be account for a reason, or some document that said how this case should be handles per-browser. just saying "you're whine about a problem i have no idea how to fix" is not cool dude.

Comment: "This element must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content". You have no content following, so there is no line break applied. source: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/br

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best solution, but if you add a white space after the `<br />` it works in Chrome.

```
<br />&nbsp;
```