# How to force a linebreak in Chrome contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contenteditable `<p> tag`

```
<p id="maincontent" class="conted" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true"></p>
```

And I have a function that insert HTML at the caret location.

Sometimes I want to add a breakline using that function. I could then insert a `<br/> tag`

But in Chromium browsers, the `<br/>` tag doesnt break line on the first line of a content editable div.

```
<p id="maincontent" class="conted" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">blabla this is my first line<br/></p>
```

Adding `<br/> tag` doesnt break line on first line

```
<p id="maincontent" class="conted" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">blabla this is my first line<div>this is my second line.<br/></div<</p>
```

But it does on every other line.

Comment: I think your answer can be found in this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008205/br-not-causing-new-line-on-chrome

Comment: Not applicable to my contenteditable div. I had a similar workaround tho, consisting of adding a <br> tag followed by a zero-width space character, encapsuled into a non-contenteditable span tag : <span contenteditable=false>&#8203;</span>. But then it prevents the user from returning to the upperline using backspace

Answer (score 0):

Using the obsolete feature "document.execCommand", I have found a workaround :

```
document.execCommand('insertText', false, "\n");
```

This insert a new line, anywhere