# tic tac toe with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a tic tac toe game using html, css, and JavaScript.I have created buttons to get input from `markbox(cell)` function and deres function called winning_condition  which cheks the conditions to win the game.

In my code it's not checking `winning_condition` properly wats it encountering problem??

Here's my code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TIC TAC TOE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cell;
    var symbol = "X";
    function markbox(cell)
    {
      if (cell.value == "     ")
      {
        cell.value = symbol;
        if (symbol == "X")
          symbol = "O";
        else
          symbol = "X";
      }
      //else 
      //{
      //alert("This square is occupied");
      //}
      if (winning_condition())
      {
        alert ("You win!");
        return;
      }
      else if(!winning_condition())
      {
        alert("You loose!");
      }
      else 
      {
        alert("Draw!")
      }
    }
    function winning_condition()
    {
      if(document.f1.b00.value==symbol && document.f1.b01.value==symbol && document.f1.b02.value==symbol)
        return true;
      else if(document.f1.b10.value==symbol && document.f1.b11.value==symbol && document.f1.b12.value==symbol)
        return true;
      else if(document.f1.b20.value==symbol && document.f1.b21.value==symbol && document.f1.b22.value==symbol)
        return true;
      else if(document.f1.b00.value==symbol && document.f1.b10.value==symbol && document.f1.b20.value==symbol)
        return true;
      else if(document.f1.b01.value==symbol && document.f1.b11.value==symbol && document.f1.b21.value==symbol)
        return true;
      else if(document.f1.b02.value==symbol && document.f1.b12.value==symbol && document.f1.b22.value==symbol)
        return true;
      else if(document.f1.b00.value==symbol && document.f1.b11.value==symbol && document.f1.b22.value==symbol)
        return true;
      else if(document.f1.b02.value==symbol && document.f1.b11.value==symbol && document.f1.b20.value==symbol)
        return true;
    }
    function clearBtn()
    {
      status = "X"
      document.f1.b00.value="   ";
      document.f1.b01.value="   ";
      document.f1.b02.value="   ";
      document.f1.b10.value="   ";
      document.f1.b11.value="   ";
      document.f1.b12.value="   ";
      document.f1.b20.value="   ";
      document.f1.b21.value="   ";
      document.f1.b22.value="   ";
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align="center">
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <form name="f1">
      <input type="button" name="b00" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)"/>
      <input type="button" name="b01" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)"/>
      <input type="button" name="b02" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)/></br>
      <input type="button" name="b10" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)"/>
      <input type="button" name="b11" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)"/>
      <input type="button" name="b12" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)"/></br>
      <input type="button" name="b20" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)"/>
      <input type="button" name="b21" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)"/>
      <input type="button" name="b22" value="     " onclick="markbox(this)"/>
      </br></br></br>
      <input type="reset" value="RESET GAME" onclick="clearBtn()">
    </form>    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend that you learn how to debug javascript code. E.g. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/15/debugging-javascript-with-chrome.aspx

Comment: In what way is it not checking `winning_condition()` properly? At a glance I don't see any way that `winning_condition()` can ever return anything except true but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: **1)** There is a missing `"` in your html. **2)** In your `clearBtn` function, you set `status = "X"` instead of `symbol = "X"`. **3)** `</br>` should be `<br>` (eventually [`<br/>` or `<br />`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br), but definitely not `</br>`). **4)** You don't need to call `winning_condition()` twice, just store its result and check that. **5)** There are only two possible outputs to your `winning_condition` function (`true` or nothing), so how come you expect three cases (`if/else if/else`)? **6)** I don't see the point of `return;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you are not closing your HTML correctly:

```
onclick="markbox(this)/>
```

Needs to be:

```
onclick="markbox(this)" />
```

(notice the " at the end).

The problem seems to be that you are resetting the symbol var at the moment you click on one of the buttons. You will always check the wrong symbol to win. Make a var last_clicked and use that in your winning_condition.

Try this code to work on:

http://jsfiddle.net/wG9G5/1/

Comment: thnx for your ans
Now I have editted the above code like this.. now if i want 2nd player must be computer then what changes should i made in this code..

Comment: What you need to do is to make a function like computerMove().

In this function you have to check which fields are not clicked on and randomly select one of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

this question has 6k views and I cant believe thats all for such a specific problem, I had nothing to do so was just playing around and wrote this, much for peoples amusement and hopefully anyone viewing this question will find it useful

```js
debug.flag=false;
var board,player,mode;
$('[value=reset]').onclick=reset;
reset();

function reset(){
  console.clear();
  result.textContent='';
  board=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];
  player=1;
  comp.style.display='block';
  select.style.display='none';
  game.style.display='none';
  $('[value=vsPlayer]').onclick=e=>vsplayer();
  $('[value=vsComputer]').onclick=e=>vscomp();
}
function vsplayer(){
  mode='vsplayer';  
  start();
}
function vscomp(){
  mode='vscomp';
  comp.style.display='none';
  select.style.display='block';
  $('[value=first]').onclick=e=>{player=1;start()}
  $('[value=second]').onclick=e=>{player=2;start()}  
}
function start(){
  comp.style.display='none';
  select.style.display='none';
  game.style.display='block';
  draw();
  if(mode==='vscomp'){
        if(player===2)calc();
  }
}

function draw(){
  var q=[' ','X','O'];
  board.forEach((row,x)=>row.forEach((col,y)=>get(x,y).textContent=q[col]));
}
table.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(
  node=>{
    var {x,y}=loc(node);
    node.onclick=e=>{
      debug(x,y);
      board[x][y]=player;
      player=player%2+1;
      draw();
      if(chk()===false){
        if(mode==='vscomp'){
              setTimeout(calc,50);
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
function loc(node){
  var x,y;
  node.parentNode.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((td,i)=>{if(td===node)x=i;});
  table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((tr,i)=>{if(tr===node.parentNode)y=i;});
  return {x,y};
}
function get(x,y){
  t=table.querySelectorAll('tr')[y];
  t=t.querySelectorAll('td')[x];
  return t;
}
function chk(){
  vert: 
    for(var y=0;y<3;y++){
      if(board[0][y]){
        for(var x=1;x<3;x++){
          if(board[x][y]!==board[0][y])continue vert;
        }
        result.textContent='win';
        debug('win vert',y);
        return 'win';
      }
    }
  horiz: 
    for(var x=0;x<3;x++){
      if(board[x][0]){
        for(var y=1;y<3;y++){
          if(board[x][y]!==board[x][0])continue horiz;
        }
        result.textContent='win';
        debug('win horiz',x);
        return 'win';
      }
    }
  diag1: {
    if(!board[0][0])break diag1;
    for(var i=1;i<3;i++){
      if(board[i][i]!==board[0][0])break diag1;
    }
    result.textContent='win';
    debug('win diag1');
    return 'win';
  }
  diag2: {
    if(!board[0][2])break diag2;
    for(var i=1;i<3;i++){
      if(board[i][2-i]!==board[0][2])break diag2;
    }
    result.textContent='win';
    debug('win diag2');
    return 'win';
  }
  draw: {
    for(var y=0;y<3;y++)
      for(var x=0;x<3;x++)
        if(!board[x][y])break draw;
    result.textContent='draw';
    debug('draw');
    return 'draw';
  }
  return false;
}
async function calc(){  
    debug.flag=debugchk.checked;
    var max=-1;
    var f;
    for(var y1=0;y1<3;y1++){
      next: for(var x1=0;x1<3;x1++){
      
        if(board[x1][y1])continue next;
        for(var p=0;p<2;p++){
          var p1=2-p;
          var t=[0,0,0,0];
          board2=structuredClone(board);
          board2[x1][y1]=p+1;
          
          for(var y=0;y<3;y++){
            c=0;
            f=true;
            for(var x=0;x<3;x++){
              if(board2[x][y]===p1){f=false;break;}
              if(board2[x][y]===p+1)c++;
            }
            if(f){
              t[c]+=1;
              debug(p,'horiz',y,c);
            }
          }
          
          for(var x=0;x<3;x++){
            c=0;
            f=true
            for(var y=0;y<3;y++){
              if(board2[x][y]===p1){f=false;break;}
              if(board2[x][y]===p+1)c++;
            }
            if(f){
              t[c]+=1;
              debug(p,'vert',x,c);
            }
          }
          
          c=0;
          f=true;
          for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            if(board2[i][i]===p1){f=false;break;}
            if(board2[i][i]===p+1)c++;
          }
          if(f){
            t[c]+=1;
            debug(p,'diag1',c);
          }
          
          c=0;
          f=true;
          for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            if(board2[i][2-i]===p1){f=false;break;}
            if(board2[i][2-i]===p+1)c++;
          }
          if(f){
            t[c]+=1;
            debug(p,'diag2',c);
          }
          
          f=fn();
          if(f>max){max=f;tx=x1;ty=y1};
          debug(p,x1,y1,t,f);
          
        }
      }      
    }
    debug(tx,ty,max);
    if(debug.flag){
      await pause();
    }
    board[tx][ty]=player;
    draw();
    chk();
    player=player%2+1;
    
    
  function fn(){
    var v=0;
    var m=[
      [
        [4,16,128],[1,8,64]
      ],
      [
        [1,8,64],[4,16,128]
      ]
    ];
    for(var i=3;i>0;i--){
      var tm=m[player-1][p][i-1];
      v+=tm*t[i];
      debug(player,p,i,t[i],tm,tm*t[i]);
    }
    return v;
  }
}
function $(sel){
  return document.querySelector(sel);
}
function debug(){
  if(!debug.flag)return;
  console.log.apply(console,arguments);
}
function pause(){
  var resolve,promise=new Promise(res=>resolve=res);
  setTimeout(fn,50);
  return promise;
  function fn(){
    $('[value=continue]').style.display='block';
    document.onmousedown=e=>{
      document.onmousedown=null;
      $('[value=continue]').style.display='none';
      resolve();
    }
  }
}
function over(type){
}//over
```

```css
body {
  font-family:arial;
  text-align:center;
}
#select {
  display:none;
}
#game {
  display:none;
}
table {
  margin:auto;
}
td {
  border:1px solid lightgray;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight:bold;
}
td,[type=button],[type=checkbox] {
  cursor:pointer;
}

h2 {
  color:blue;
  clear:both;
  margin:0;
}
h3 {
  margin:0;
}
input {
  font-size:16px;
}

#debug {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#debugchk {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#debuglabel {
}

[value=continue] {
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
  height:35px;
  font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<div id=debug>
  <span id=debuglabel>debug</span>
  <input id=debugchk type=checkbox>
</div>

<h2>Tic Tac Toe</h2>

<div id=comp>
  <input value=vsComputer type=button>
  <input value=vsPlayer type=button>
</div>

<div id=select>
  choose : 
  <input value=first type=button>
  <input value=second type=button>
</div>

<div id=game>
  <table id=table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <input value=reset type=button>
  <h3 id=result></h3>
</div>

<input value=continue type=button>
```

if youre using debug mode, its best to go full page, open dev tools and give it some space

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, you just wrote another tic tac toe. Besides, I played a bit your version against computer, and it says "Win" regardless who wins (me or the computer)

Comment: Yeah this question has 6k views because this question is over 10 years old. Also if a person is stuck with his 'Tic-tac-toe', your solution is not going to help him/her.