# Tic Tac Toe Game JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can not get the button in my javascript to reset to be able to play the game again.

Here is a link to the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/jbirdwell/Q3wEZ/

HTML:

```
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<button>New Game</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var x = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').click(function () {
        if (!x) {
            $(this).toggleClass('user1');
            x = true;
        } else {
            $(this).toggleClass('user2');
            x = false;
        }
    });

    $('button').click(function () {
        $('div').toggleClass('newgame');
    });    
});
```

Once the button click event is executed I can not go back to beginning to play again.

Comment: It seems that you have some misunderstanding on CSS. `$('div').toggleClass('newgame')` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have learned now. I began learning Html & Javascript yesterday.

Comment: i wrote a little tic-tac-toe, maybe you find it useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152494/tic-tac-toe-with-javascript/77214609#77214609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something more like...

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').removeClass("user1 user2");
});
```

Comment: This works! Thank you, Alex! I am learning and this is my exploration of the past few hours.

Comment: @Jbirdwell Don't forget to reset your `x` variable as well, if you care to differ between the players on the 2nd game.

Comment: Awesome. I reset the x to false. It works now thank you. I had been fighting with this problem for a good hour.

Answer (score 2):

It's because they still have the other classes, try changing it to :

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').toggleClass('newgame');
    $('div').removeClass('user1 user2');
    x = false;
});
```

Should work

Comment: The `newgame` class isn't really needed anymore.

Comment: True, but perhaps he needs it for other reasons. It's enough to work it out yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you change the color of the fields, they still have the "user1" and "user2" classes. So what you'll have to do is reset those.

I have changed your code to make it work, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3wEZ/4/)

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $("div").removeClass("user1");
    $("div").removeClass("user2");
});
```