# Simple Javascript Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a simple tic-tac toe game, but I'm having a problem with two things:

1. My 3x3 board does not split into different rows - when I try to make more game tiles it just puts it along the same row
2. I can create new X and O images by copying my code at the bottom, but I do not know how to lock them in place once they've been played.

Here's my current HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #div1 {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        float:left;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }
    function drop(ev) {
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    </script>
    <title>JavaScript  Drag &amp; Drop Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Drag the X and O images into the tic-tac-toe board:</p>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>


        <img id="drag1" src="X.png" draggable="true" 
            ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75" />
        <img id="drag2" src="O.png" draggable="true" 
            ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: To put items on the same line, apply css `display; inline-block`. To put items on different lines, apply css `display: block` (or just use a table, it's much simpler and makes sense for a tic-tac-toe grid).

Comment: i wrote a little tic-tac-toe, maybe you find it useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152494/tic-tac-toe-with-javascript/77214609#77214609

Answer (score 1):

You can't  give the same id to each div ,id must have unique for each div. You have to take a class at the place of id. we can give same class name to many divs. You can try this code.

```js
<SCRIPT>


if (document.all||document.getElementById){
    document.write('<style>.tictac{')
    document.write('width:50px;height:50px;')
    document.write('}</style>')
}

var sqr1
var sqr2
var sqr3
var sqr4
var sqr5
var sqr6
var sqr7
var sqr8
var sqr9
var sqr1T = 0
var sqr2T = 0
var sqr3T = 0
var sqr4T = 0
var sqr5T = 0
var sqr6T = 0
var sqr7T = 0
var sqr8T = 0
var sqr9T = 0
var moveCount = 0
var turn = 0
var mode = 1

function vari()
{
    sqr1 = document.tic.sqr1.value
    sqr2 = document.tic.sqr2.value
    sqr3 = document.tic.sqr3.value
    sqr4 = document.tic.sqr4.value
    sqr5 = document.tic.sqr5.value
    sqr6 = document.tic.sqr6.value
    sqr7 = document.tic.sqr7.value
    sqr8 = document.tic.sqr8.value
    sqr9 = document.tic.sqr9.value
}
function check()
{
    if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr2 == " X " && sqr3 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr6 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr4 == " X " && sqr7 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr8 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr7 == " X ")
    {
        alert("You Win!")
        reset()
    }
    else
    {
        winCheck()
        check2()
        drawCheck()
    }
}

function check2()
{
    vari()
    drawCheck()
    if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr2 == " O " && sqr3 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr6 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr4 == " O " && sqr7 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr8 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr7 == " O ")
    {
        alert("You Lose!")
        reset()
    }
}

function player1Check()
{
    if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr2 == " X " && sqr3 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr6 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr4 == " X " && sqr7 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr8 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr7 == " X ")
    {
        alert("Player 1 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else
    {
        player2Check()
        drawCheck()
    }
}

function player2Check()
{
    vari()
    drawCheck()
    if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr2 == " O " && sqr3 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr6 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr4 == " O " && sqr7 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr8 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr7 == " O ")
    {
        alert("Player 2 wins!")
        reset()
    }
}

function drawCheck()
{
    vari()
    moveCount = sqr1T + sqr2T + sqr3T + sqr4T + sqr5T + sqr6T + sqr7T + sqr8T + sqr9T
    if(moveCount == 9)
    {
        reset()
        alert("Draw")
    }
}

function winCheck()
{
    check2()
    if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr2 == " O " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
        sqr3T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr3 == " O " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
        sqr1T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
        sqr6T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr5 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr4T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
        sqr4T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        sqr9T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr8 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
        sqr7T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        sqr9T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr5 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
        sqr1T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
        sqr7T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
        sqr3T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr3 == " O " && sqr2T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
        sqr2T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        sqr5T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr8T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
        sqr8T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr7 == " O " && sqr4T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
        sqr4T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        sqr5T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
        sqr6T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        sqr9T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr7 == " O " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
        sqr1T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr5 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr2T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
        sqr2T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr6 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
        sqr3T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr4 == " O " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
        sqr7T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr8T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
        sqr8T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        sqr9T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        sqr5T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr7 == " O " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        sqr5T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        computer()
    }
    check2()
}
function computer()
{
    check2()
    if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr2 == " X " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
        sqr3T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr3 == " X " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
        sqr1T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
        sqr6T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr5 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr4T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
        sqr4T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        sqr9T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr8 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
        sqr7T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        sqr9T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
        sqr1T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
        sqr7T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
        sqr3T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr3 == " X " && sqr2T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
        sqr2T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        sqr5T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr8T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
        sqr8T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr7 == " X " && sqr4T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
        sqr4T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        sqr5T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
        sqr6T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        sqr9T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr7 == " X " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
        sqr1T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr5 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr2T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
        sqr2T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr6 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
        sqr3T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr4 == " X " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
        sqr7T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr8T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
        sqr8T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        sqr9T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        sqr5T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr7 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        sqr5T = 1;
        turn = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        AI()
    }
    check2()
}

function AI()
{
    vari()
    if(document.tic.sqr5.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr5T = 1
    }
    else if(document.tic.sqr1.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr1T = 1
    }
    else if(document.tic.sqr9.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr9T = 1
    }
    else if(document.tic.sqr6.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr6T = 1
    }
    else if(document.tic.sqr2.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr2T = 1
    }
    else if(document.tic.sqr8.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr8T = 1
    }
    else if(document.tic.sqr3.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr3T = 1
    }
    else if(document.tic.sqr7.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr7T = 1
    }
    else if(document.tic.sqr4.value == "     " && turn == 1)
    {
        document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
        turn = 0
        sqr4T = 1
    }
    check2()
}

function reset()
{
    document.tic.sqr1.value = "     "
    document.tic.sqr2.value = "     "
    document.tic.sqr3.value = "     "
    document.tic.sqr4.value = "     "
    document.tic.sqr5.value = "     "
    document.tic.sqr6.value = "     "
    document.tic.sqr7.value = "     "
    document.tic.sqr8.value = "     "
    document.tic.sqr9.value = "     "
    sqr1T = 0
    sqr2T = 0
    sqr3T = 0
    sqr4T = 0
    sqr5T = 0
    sqr6T = 0
    sqr7T = 0
    sqr8T = 0
    sqr9T = 0
    vari()
    turn = 0
    moveCount = 0
}

function resetter()
{
    reset()
}
</SCRIPT>

<FORM NAME="tic" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr1" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr1.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr1.value = ' X '; sqr1T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr1.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr1.value = ' X '; sqr1T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr1.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr1.value = ' O '; sqr1T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr2" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr2.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr2.value = ' X '; sqr2T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr2.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr2.value = ' X '; sqr2T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr2.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr2.value = ' O '; sqr2T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr3" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr3.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr3.value = ' X '; sqr3T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr3.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr3.value = ' X '; sqr3T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr3.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr3.value = ' O '; sqr3T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()"><br />
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr4" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr4.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr4.value = ' X '; sqr4T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr4.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr4.value = ' X '; sqr4T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr4.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr4.value = ' O '; sqr4T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr5" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr5.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr5.value = ' X '; sqr5T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr5.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr5.value = ' X '; sqr5T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr5.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr5.value = ' O '; sqr5T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr6" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr6.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr6.value = ' X '; sqr6T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr6.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr6.value = ' X '; sqr6T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr6.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr6.value = ' O '; sqr6T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()"><br />
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr7" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr7.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr7.value = ' X '; sqr7T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr7.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr7.value = ' X '; sqr7T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr7.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr7.value = ' O '; sqr7T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr8" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr8.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr8.value = ' X '; sqr8T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr8.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr8.value = ' X '; sqr8T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr8.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr8.value = ' O '; sqr8T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr9" class="tictac" value="     " onClick="if(document.tic.sqr9.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 1) {document.tic.sqr9.value = ' X '; sqr9T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); check();} else if(document.tic.sqr9.value == '     ' && turn == 1 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr9.value = ' X '; sqr9T = 1; turn = 0; vari(); player1Check()} else if(document.tic.sqr9.value == '     ' && turn == 0 && mode == 2) {document.tic.sqr9.value = ' O '; sqr9T = 1; turn = 1; vari(); player1Check()} drawCheck()">
</form>
```

You can't give same id to each div, You have to use Class at the place of id .

Answer (score 0):

In your `allowDrop(event)` you need to access the drop target in DOM and remove the ondragover event. This way it wouldn't be a drop target anymore.

To learn about this, check the following resources

- [HTML5 Drag & Drop specifications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html)
- [Tutorial on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)
- [Tutorial on HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)
- [HTMLGoodies article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/html-5-drag-drop-basics.html)

... and [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+drag+%26+drop+tutorial)

I used to teach programming with VB using Tic-Tac-Toe as example, nice to see that implemented in JavaScript too.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that

Comment: @user2923395 I believe the "drop target in DOM" he is referring to would be your `div`s and when he says remove the `ondragover` event he means dynamically remove the attribute which can be done with jQuery.