# How can I add a second line of text within an <li> tag?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am using the wonderful Slickmap template to start creating a tree for a friend but cannot work out how to have multiple lines of text within the same `<li>` tag. Basically the first 5 items should be within the same box and then the last two in separate boxes. I've tried all variants of `<br>` I can think of including adding a `&nbsp;` after the `<br>` but nothing seems to work. Is it possible and if so how?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/acceptance">Acceptance</a></br>
    <a href="/IPC-DRM-PTH">IPC-DRM-PTH</a></br>
    <a href="/IPC-A-610">IPC-A-610</a></br>
    <a href="/IPC-9191">IPC-9191</a></br>
    <a href="/IPC-DRM-SMT">IPC-DRM-SMT</a></br>
    <a href="/Posters">Posters</a></br>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/mission">Mission Statement</a></li>
    <li><a href="/principals">Principals</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Example web page](http://fieldshypnotherapy.co.uk/SlickmapCSS/index.html)

Comment: It's <br />. Have you tried making the links block display in css?

Comment: Hi Phix Just tried that but that doesn't seem to work either [link]http://fieldshypnotherapy.co.uk/SlickmapCSS/index.html[/link]. Sorry not all that experienced, how would I make them block display? think they are already? `code`#primaryNav {
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
#primaryNav #home {
 display: block;
 float: none;
 background: #ffffff url('images/L1-left.png') center bottom no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 padding: 0 0 30px 0;
}
#primaryNav li {
 float: left;
 background: url('images/L1-center.png') center top no-repeat;
 padding: 30px 0;
 margin-top: -30px;
}

Answer (score 1):

The `</br>` should be `<br>`. Then you're fine.

The `</li>` means "close this li (list item) element". A br element does not need a closing tag. Since it cannot contain any content, it's closed implicitly. You may see `<br/>` sometimes though. This basically comes down to an br element that is immediately closed afterwards. Note the position of the forward slash.

See also [HTML 5: Is it <br>, <br/>, or <br />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br)

Comment: Hi meryn thanks for your answer. I had already tried <br> before posting but that also didn't work