# Am I delusional about Html encoding?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-encode

I seem to be hitting a logical contradiction. I have a view with...

`</br>` in the markup and when I load the page it shows a new line. Inspecting the source I can see a `</br>`.

Then I put `@Html.Raw("</br>")` and in the source I get `&lt;/br&gt;`

However all the documentation says that by default razor will html encode all strings. So why does Html.Raw show an encoded string instead?

Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Try using `<br/>` instead.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested over here and I got `</br>`

Comment: And you should see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1946426/340760

Comment: im quite sure that when I put </br> on a view that is what I get in the source but that is not htmlencoded....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`</br>` is incorrect, you probably meant `<br/>`.

This being said, here's how it works:

```
<br/> generates <br/>
@("<br/>") generates &lt;br/&gt;
@Html.Raw("<br/>") generates <br/>
```

The `Html.Raw` helper is used when you do not want to get HTML encoded output in the resulting HTML. By default the `@` Razor function HTML encodes its argument.

Comment: if <br/> generates <br/> and <br/> is html encoded. How come when I go to a html encoding site and enter <br/> and click encode I get &lt;br/&gt; ? Doesnt make any sense, they are both html encoded?

Comment: `&lt;br/&gt;` is the HTML encoded representation of the `<br/>` string. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: If I start with <br/> and html encode it do I end up with <br/> or &lt;br/&gt;?  you say its the html encoded representation what does this mean? To encode something is to change it to another string that can be interpreted in another way. I just cant see why sometimes I end up with <br/> in the source or  &lt;br/&gt;?

Answer (score -1):

From W3schools (I know it ain't W3C official)

Differences Between HTML and XHTML

In HTML, the `<br>` tag has no end tag.
In XHTML, the `<br>` tag must be properly closed, like this: `<br />`.

I don't know about razor it's @Html function but you don't need the '/' at all