# How to print array and <br> with single echo function

Tags: php, arrays

Here is simple line of code:

```
echo $array2[3]."<br>";
```

The `.` Operator is appending `<br>` with array resulting into the following error:

> Array to string conversion

I don't want to use `{$array2[3]}` like that. Is there any way to put both things in echo seperated?

**Edit**: Is there any way to print array with Echo

Comment: Looks like `$array2[3]` is an array, so if you want to output it for debugging purposes, use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

Comment: You should use `<br />`.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert How do you know its xhtml? It might as well be html. Anyway it is not part of the question.

Comment: Like all the others previously said, use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to have `array` `keys` and `values` printed on the next line. I would recommend `var_dump()` over `print_r()` to be honest.

Comment: You'd get the same error using only `echo $array2[3];`. *Hint, hint #thinkaboutit #xyproblem #facebookhashashtagstoo*

Comment: @EdwinLambregts Hey thanks it was array inside array, how do i print array with echo

Comment: @MarkEvans You mean something like $array2[3][4]?

Comment: @EdwinLambregts I meant whole array

Answer (score 3):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) on your array with your desired delimiter.

```
echo implode("<br />", $yourArray);
```

As mentioned in the comments it's advised to use <br /> instead of <br> when you want' to use the echo inside a web application.

If you want to debug the array it's better to use print_r() or var_dump().

Comment: Why is it better to use `<br />`?

Comment: Depending on what you output. In HTML, the <br> tag has no end tag.
In XHTML, the <br> tag must be properly closed, like this: <br />.
Also have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br) for further informations.

Comment: That means, `<br />` will work whatever the document type? Cool, thanks!