# Using <br> instead of <br />

Tags: html, browser-support

When I started learning HTML from w3schools, they were using this `<br />`. As I started learning ASP.NET, on their forum ([ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net)) I was told to use `<br>`. So I started using the second one.

**My Question:** What is the difference between `<br>` and `<br />`? Is there something like browser support?

Comment: You can use whatever you are fine with, `<br />` the xhtml thing where you need to self close the tags, it's strict

Comment: See this link: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?435290-difference-between-lt-br-gt-and-lt-br-gt

Comment: The link by @user2520969 is more preferable, as it has almost the answer I was hoping for. The link that was provided as a duplicate might look alike, but I am not sure it is a duplicate for that. However, might be a duplicate. And the answer of cdhowie helped me out by providing that example of XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lone `<br>` is invalid in XHTML, since XML documents must close each tag they open.  `<br />` is semantically the same as `<br></br>` in XML documents, and is referred to as a *self-closing tag*, so `<br />` is used when writing XHTML, or HTML documents that will be read by an XML parser.

This applies to all other tags that do not have a closing tag in HTML, such as `<hr />` and `<meta />`.

Both are valid HTML, so there is no reason not to use `<br />`, unless you are writing for a broken HTML parser.

---

Note that in XML, `<br/>` is valid.  However, older HTML parsers that don't know about self-closing tags have been known to choke on this.  If a space is inserted before the tag name and the self-closing tag token (`/`) then these parsers see `/` as an attribute, or as noise that is discarded.  Therefore, one should always make sure to put a space between the element name and the self-closing tag token for compatibility with these broken parsers.

Comment: So that means, `<br />` usage is better? But what if I am not using XHTML, and neither I am using XML, is the usage of `<br>` legal?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan A proper HTML parser will consider both `<br>` and `<br />` as legal, yes.

Comment: @ironicaldiction There is no difference in HTML.  `<br />` is preferred not because of some notion of style, but because it allows the document to be read using an XML parser.

Comment: So that means, `<br>` is not allowed in XML files, as they require a closing tag too. Nice anwer.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Yes.  You could write `<br></br>` but this would confuse older HTML parsers.  The `<br />` syntax (including the space) is XML-compatible while also working well with older HTML parsers that don't understand self-closing tags.

Comment: @ironicaldiction, I just visited the page you are mentioning, and after that! I was forced to come to this site to ask what's the right way to use this tag. Nothing else. As in start they post the `<br />` then they use `<br>`.

Comment: However, I never meant to give a closing tag for `<br>`. Its just a line break. I was saying the XML needs to be closed, sorry you mis understood!

Comment: Afzaal, My earlier comment was irrelevant.  Didn't mean to confuse you.

Comment: @cdhowie, please correct all your claims of <br></br> being fine and only confusing old parsers. It is simply not allowed to have closing tags for a selvclosing tag. <br> and <br /> are the only valid ones.

Comment: @Brunis No, that's [not true in XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2), though it can (and probably will) confuse user agents that can parse HTML, but not XHTML.  If an XHTML parser does not understand `<br></br>` then it is a broken XHTML parser.

Comment: I read the grey box with the duplicate answer and saw HTML5, i realize this question was not standards specific. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

`<br>` is the valid way to do this in HTML, and `<br/>` is the way to do it in XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br), but anyways, there is no difference other than preference, at least in HTML. In XML, `<br />` is more correct.