# Form submitting twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am making an query form. i am new with jquery. after reading the jquery validation plugin and ajax i wrote the following code. this code first validate the form and then submit the form via ajax. if i submit form the form submit twice. the result coming two times
I am not able to get err.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            },
            security: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: '* Please Enter Your Name.'
            },
            email: {
                required: "* Please Enter Your E-mail  ",
                email: "* Please enter proper E-mail  "
            },
            address: {
                required: "* Please enter address."
            },
            message: {
                required: "* Please enter Enquiry"
            },
            security: {
                required: "* Please enter Security code"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // Ajax Submit here

            // alert($("#contactForm").serialize());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "assets/sendmail.php",
                data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == 'Success') {
                        $("#contactForm").hide();
                        $("#contact_response").html('<div class="alert alert-success">Thank you for your feedback.</div>');
                    } else {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

the html form is

```
 <form action="assets/sendmail.php" method="post" name="contactForm" id="contactForm" >
                    <!-- STEP-2 : GENERAL SETTINGS -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="success_page" value="../contact-us?res=thank-you" id="success_page" /><!-- PAGE TO REDIRECT AFTER SUBMIT -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="email_to" value="<?=get_settings('contact_email');?>" id="email_to" /><!-- EMAIL ADDRESS WHERE WE WANT TO RECEIVE EMAIL -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="email_subject" value="Query Recieved" id="email_subject" /><!-- SUBJECT OF THE EMAIL -->
                    <!-- STEP-2 : GENERAL SETTINGS -->

                    <label for="name" class="nameLabel">Name</label>
                      <input id="name" type="text" name="name"   />
                    <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
                          <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                      <input id="address" type="text" name="address"  />
                    <label for="message" class="messageLabel">Enquiry</label>
                      <textarea id="message" name="message"  /></textarea>
                    <label >Security Code</label> 
                        <img src="classes/CaptchaSecurityImages.php?width=100&amp;height=30&amp;characters=5" alt="captcha" style="vertical-align:bottom;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="security" name="security" class="required" type="text" style="width:30%;vertical-align:bottom;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;"/></br>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
                    </script>
```

Comment: What is the HTML code for the form?

Comment: i have edited. plz check it...

Comment: Add `onsubmit='return:false;'` to your form to prevent the default submit action.

Comment: or use `<button type="button">` instead

Comment: @ammarkhan I think it may be because of `action="assets/sendmail.php"` in your form, since you already have it in your Ajax. Try removing it.

Comment: @Virendra giving error unexpected token : err

Comment: @Fred-ii- still submitting form tw times

Comment: @Gracchus if i do <button type="button"> form is not submitting

Comment: @ammarkhan Then try `event.preventDefault();` after `$('#contactForm').validate({` or after `submitHandler: function (form) {`

Comment: @ammarkhan I just noticed something. You have `</script>` at the end of your form. That should not be there, and it (`</script>`) is missing at the end of your JS.

Comment: What @Virendra really meant to say was `onsubmit="return false;"`.

Comment: @Virendra, When you use this plugin, you absolutely, positively, **do not** put a `onsubmit='return:false;'` in the `form` tag! The submit event is already properly captured by the plugin and inline event handlers are completely unnecessary with jQuery.

Comment: Big mistake by me ....validating the form two times......first one was hiding somewhere in script file. due to which this script is not working...now i got the solution thanks for all....

Answer (score 1):

[Your HTML & JavaScript code is working](http://jsfiddle.net/a2xdg/).

However, within your OP, it appears as if you've surrounded both your jQuery and your HTML within one set of `<script></script>` tags...

You have a `<script>` tag at the start of your JavaScript....

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            ....
```

and you have a closing `</script>` tag at the end of your HTML...

```
         ....
    </form>
</script>
```

You cannot do this and it will likely break the whole page.  Only enclose the JavaScript within `<script></script>` tags...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#contactForm').validate({
            // rules, options, etc.
        });

    });
</script>
```

You also do not need `action="assets/sendmail.php"` within your `<form>` tag.  You already have `.ajax()` to send your data to `assets/sendmail.php` using the `submitHandler` of the jQuery Validation plugin.

---

Two other minor HTML issues I noticed...

1)  You have a closing `</br>` tag.  [This is invalid HTML because there is no such thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946452/594235).  [`BR` is considered an "empty" or "void" tag](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/br.html) so you'll either just use `<br>` alone, or "self-close" it: `<br />`.  (note the critical position of the slash `/`)

2)  Your `textarea` is written like this:  `<textarea /></textarea>`.  This is invalid HTML because you cannot "self-close" `textarea` when it already has a closing tag, `</textarea>`.  You simply write it like this:  `<textarea></textarea>`.

**DEMO with corrected HTML and working jQuery Validation:**  http://jsfiddle.net/a2xdg/

Answer (score 1):

Just write the following logic in your php code:

```
if(!empty($email)){
  @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
}
```

This will prevent sending an email with empty values.