# Menu rollover images and text only working on one

Tags: html, css

I have a rollover menu that displays the days of the week. They originally sat happily side by side each other with an image that appeared when hovered over. Now I'm trying to get **text** and an **image** to appear when you hover over a day. The text works on the first day ("Thurs") but the rest of the days don't appear, nor does the hover image background.

What am I doing wrong? Pls go easy on me, i'm trying!

I've also made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhmNX/1/) (this is how the menu [originally looked](http://jsfiddle.net/vnV8j/11/))

THE HTML

```
  <div id="nav">
  <ul class="menu">
  <li>
  <div class="img1 left"> <a href="" id="thursButton" class="thursButton"></a>

  <p>Somewhere Only We Know Lily Allen
  <br/>Story Of My Life One Direction
  <br/>
  </p>
  </div>
    </li>
    <li>

<div class="img2 left"> <a href="" id="friButton" class="friButton"></a>

 <p>Somewhere Only We Know Lily Allen
 <br/>Story Of My Life One Direction
 <br/>
 </p>
  </div>
  </li>
  <li>
```

THE CSS

```
#nav {
display:inline;
list-style: none;
position: fixed;
width: 1290px;
margin: 0 auto; 
left:0px; 
right:0px;
float:clear;
top: 120px;
z-index: 1000;

}
.menu li {
display: inline;
vertical-align:top; 
float:left;

 }
.menu li a {
display: block;
height: 407px;
width:250px;
text-indent: -999999px;
}
.img1 {
width: 250px;
height: 407px;
position: relative;
}
 .thursButton {
  width:250px;
  height:177px;
  display:block;
  }
  #thursButton {
  background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/K8umxhswx/thu.png');
  }
  .thursButton:hover {
   background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/6Rxmxht1d/thu-hover.png');
  }
.img2 {
width: 250px;
height: 407px;
position: relative;
}
.satButton {
width:250px;
height:177px;
display:block;
}
#satButton {
background-image:url(http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/drJmxhstf/sat.png');
}
.satButton:hover {
 background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/qfsmxhstx/sat-hover.png');
}
.left p {
color: #FFFFFF;
display: none;
font-size: 18px;
left: 10px;
position: absolute;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
top: 100px;
width: 250px;
}
.left:hover p {

display:block;
}
```

Comment: A lot of errors in your HTML.
<br> must be <br/>.
You are closing <p> and <a> twice...

Comment: `<br>` is generally accepted as usage du jour (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br) But jsfiddle always complains. It's perfectly valid for HTML documents, if not XHTML it should be used vs `<br />`

Comment: At a minimum, your list markup is invalid.

Comment: @ExtPro You are right, but I still believe that for a better portability we should always use the closing one.

Comment: There's only `Thu` in your fiddle. How can we check the other days? Also, do you really need background images to get your text to look like this?

Comment: @tewathia, there's Fri too.. just scroll down

Comment: @ExtPro I removed the <br> but the rest of the menu still isn't appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this looks somewhat presentable:

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="thursButton" class="thursButton">
                <div class="img1 left">
                    <p>Somewhere Only We Know Lily Allen<br/>Story Of My Life One Direction</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="friButton" class="friButton">
                <div class="img2 left">
                    <p>Somewhere Only We Know Lily Allen<br/>Story Of My Life One Direction</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="satButton" class="satButton">
                <div class="img3 left">
                    <p>Somewhere Only We Know Lily Allen<br/>Story Of My Life One Direction</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
    position:fixed;
    width:1290px;
    margin:0 auto; 
    left:0px; 
    right:0px;
    float:clear;
    top:120px;
    z-index:1000;
}

.menu li {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:top; 
    float:left;
}

.menu li a {
    display:block;
    height:407px;
    width:250px;
}

.img1 {
    width:250px;
    height:407px;
    position:relative;
}

.thursButton {
    width:250px;
    height:177px;
    display:block;
}

#thursButton {
    background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/K8umxhswx/thu.png');
}

#thursButton:hover {
    background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/6Rxmxht1d/thu-hover.png');
}

.img2 {
    width:250px;
    height:407px;
    position:relative;
}

.friButton {
    width:250px;
    height:177px;
    display:block;
}

#friButton {
    background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/9dtmxhsw1/fri.png');
}

#friButton:hover {
    background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/dCtmxht0o/fri-hover.png');
}

.img3 {
    width:250px;
    height:407px;
    position:relative;
}

.satButton {
    width:250px;
    height:177px;
    display:block;
}

#satButton {
    background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/drJmxhstf/sat.png');
}

#satButton:hover {
    background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/qfsmxhstx/sat-hover.png');
}

.left p {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:none;
    font-size:18px;
    left:10px;
    position:absolute;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
    top:100px;
    width:250px;
}

.left:hover p {
    display:block;
}
```

There were multiple errors with incorrectly closed tags.

I suggest Using a HTML or CSS Validator to troubleshoot future issues:

http://validator.w3.org/ For HTML

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ For CSS

Comment: Ah ok, so I position the img as 'relative' and the button is 'display:block'?

Comment: How do you get the hover image to appear tho? I created a hover section but it only shows the original img

Comment: also I cleaned up my html http://jsfiddle.net/arp8D/7/ thank you for those two links :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Should work better now. I suggest getting a text editor like Notepad++ so you can notice errors thanks to syntax highlighting. It makes your job a lot easier and it's also freeware.

Comment: Amazing, thank you @WP_. Just so I understand and can learn for future ref - did you remove the text-indent and add a # instead of . on the hover?

Comment: Yes. The `text-indent` is redundant because the <p>-texts are already set to `display:none;`. I changed the hover thingies to id's (#) rather than classes (.). You were using CSS code for the classes "thursButton", "friButton" and "satButton" to set their background image. But you also used id's to change the background image when hovering. That doesn't work at all. Either use classes or id's, not both, when using pseudo-classes like `:hover` or `:focus` for a specific element. Practice makes perfect!

Comment: Thank you, @WP_! Your help has been invaluable!

Comment: Could i possibly pester you for a tiny bit longer? The menu has knocked the alignment of the site content http://tinyurl.com/o46hj3b. Any ideas why?

Comment: I suggest that you get a good developer tool like FireBug if you use Firefox. Many browsers already have an integrated developer tool that you can use by clicking F12. Use the element inspector button (usually an arrow and a square icon) and then click on any element on your page to view the HTML code and the CSS rules that affects it. I also recommend fixing the DOCTYPE error on your webpage before doing any heavy work. If the DOCTYPE is not correct, your code is not guaranteed to work as you'd expect.

Comment: Sorry, @WP_... one final question, I promise. When I hover up the text, the hover image disappears tinyurl.com/o46hj3b. I checked with firebug and couldnt see anything unusual :-/