# Ruby on Rails Button too close to form

Tags: html, css

I'm new to Ruby and programming in general. I'm creating this log in page using simple form but the Create account button is to close to the confirm password form I don't know how to enter a break between these two.

Thank you!

```
 <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Correo Electronico' %>

  <%= f.input :password, :label => 'Contraseña' %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => 'Confirmar Contraseña' %>



  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Crear cuenta", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is purely css question.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1946446/834582

Comment: quick and dirty: put a `<br/>` between your password input and your submit button

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: Seems like you're using Bootstrap. SimpleForm's [integration](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#bootstrap) should ensure a proper spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a HTML class/id and put these rules in a CSS file. But there is 2 ways:

**The quick & diry way**:

```
<div style="margin-top: 15px;">
  <%= f.submit "Crear cuenta", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

---

**The proper way**:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss (or extension can be .sass)
body div.form_action_buttons {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

# your view
<div class='form_action_buttons'>
  <%= f.submit "Crear cuenta", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```