# <Span> not showing inside <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In chrome the `<span class="co">` is not showing. [The fiddle for the whole website is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gu7gC/)

If I remove `<p class="text-box">` or set the `</p>` before the `<span class="co">` all the CSS need for it to look fine is removed.

**HTML for one of the parts involved**

```
<p class="text-box">Du mister beskyttelsen ved å gjøre en av disse tingene</p>
            <b><p class="text-box">Som Traitor</p></b>
        <p class="text-box"
   <span class="co">Skyte med våpen
            <br>Prop kill</br>
            <br>Goomba stomp</br>
            <br>Dra ut et traitor våpen</br>
            <br>Eller hvis for mange spillere er proven</br>
  </span></p>
```

**CSS**

```
    .co {
    font-family: 'Consolas', 'monospace';
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(64,64,64);
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .box-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

.box-wrap p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #717171;
}
```

I'm stuck in my ways and I don't know what to do

Comment: you are missing a closing `>` on your `<p>` tag

Comment: First you should try simply running your code through the w3 validator, http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: why dont u close tag <p           ? do it like <p>

Comment: PD: In fiddle don't copy all Jquery library.

Comment: @Caimen , is it free service?

Comment: @Caimen don't get me wrong, this question is silly and I agree he could have put a small amount of effort into fixing it, but I wouldn't jump to W3C to hunt for a problem :P

Comment: Tip: On your fiddle you can import jquery under the "Frameworks and extensions" option in the upper right hand corner instead of pasting it into the javascript section.

Comment: he has text wrapped in <br> tags... both opened and closed...

Comment: @adrichman It's at the end of the HTML code, as I said in my main post the CSS is gone if I set the </p> before <span>

Comment: @user3549699 No, you're missing the point. you have `<p class="text-box"` which should be................ `<p class="text-box">` note the missing `>`

Comment: @PratikJoshi, yes, the W3 validator is a free service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix all of the `<p>` tags so that they close and it should work... I also cleaned up your fiddle so that you don't have unnecessary code in it...

http://jsfiddle.net/Gu7gC/2/

```
<p class="text-box"> <--- This is what you need to fix
   <span class="co">Skyte med våpen
            Prop kill<br/>
            Goomba stomp<br/>
            Dra ut et traitor våpen<br/>
            Eller hvis for mange spillere er proven<br/>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: This worked, and I was stupid enough to think that I needed </br>. Thank you for doing this.

Comment: -1 br is an empty tag. It does not have an end tag. Please check this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: @RupamDatta copy and paste error... why didn't you edit it? wasn't answering anything in regards to the `<br/>` tag

Comment: @RupamDatta, please [avoid referencing w3schools](http://w3fools.com). The Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) is a much better resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: @Chris, well the point I made was not to use start and end tag for br tag since br tag is an empty or singleton tag. I referred w3schools because even they say the correct use of br tag. Otherwise, there are many other references which I could make. In stackoverflow itself there are questions asked and solved on proper usage of br tag. refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Comment: @RupamDatta, I understand the point you were making. But w3schools is a poor resource and we should avoid it when possible.

Comment: @Chris I understand that. I personally don't go there. I googled and w3schools was the first choice so I put the link. Thanks for raising this point.

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle contains some serious errors, a lot of tags are not closed properly, if you look through the code you will see some code marked in red, these are not closed properly and are most likely causing your problem.

Comment: "a lot" http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Answer (score 0):

you are missing closing of

`<p class="text-box"> 
   <span class="co">Skyte med våpen
            <br>Prop kill</br>
            <br>Goomba stomp</br>
            <br>Dra ut et traitor våpen</br>
            <br>Eller hvis for mange spillere er proven</br>
 </span></p>`

and be sure that all tags have their closings.

span is just like a content holder as div. So it is better to use span to hold p tag rather than using span inside p tag.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect DOM is the cause of you problem. Please correct that first. Following is an example.

```
<p class="text-box">
     Du mister beskyttelsen ved å gjøre en av disse tingene
</p>
<p class="text-box">Som Traitor</p>
<p class="text-box">
    <span class="co">
        Skyte med våpen
        Prop kill<br />
        Goomba stomp<br />
        Dra ut et traitor våpen<br />
        Eller hvis for mange spillere er proven<br />
    </span>
</p>
```

I feel you have to check about HTML tags and the usage. For instance, br tag is a singleton tag. i.e., it does not have start (`<br>`) and end(`</br>`) tags as you have used. Its `<br />`

The other instance is 'span' is an inline element and 'p' is a block element. Semantically correct html cannot have a block element inside an inline element. Similarly, you cannot put 'p' element inside 'b' element.

I'd ask you to go through the HTML first and I expect all your problems will automatically be solved.

Appreciate your time. Thanks!

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/Gu7gC/3/)**