# String to Array to <br/> list

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a item that gives me a result of `string(26) "cake1 cake2 cake3 cake4"`

The cake result comes from `$_POST()`

What would be the best way to make it so the final result is like:

`cake1
 cake2`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace the spaces with `<br>`'s?

```
echo str_replace(' ', '<br />', $_POST['cake_list']);
```

Of course you should sanitize the POST, but this is a quick example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a string like this

```
$str = "cake1 cake2 cake3 cake4";
```

convert your string to array like this

```
$arr = exploade(" ",$str);
```

show the elements of the array with `<br>` tag like this

```
foreach ($arr as $value)
   echo $value . "<br>";
```