# What form of meta tag is valid in HTML5 <meta> or <meta/>?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Validators accept both form of tag `<meta>` and `<meta/>`. HTML5 [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) says that no end tag should be present, hence the form of `<meta><meta/>` is prohibited. But I could not find any information about form `<meta/>`.

Comment: AFAIK it is not prohibited. It is all up to you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML 5: Is it <br> <br/> or <br />?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br)

Comment: The question concerns formal specification _not_ the differences between HTML and XHTML (of which I aware of). @abhitalks has pointed out to proper section of HTML specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this HTML5 standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

> Start tags consist of the following parts, in exactly the following
> order:
>
> 1. A "<" character.
> 2. The element’s tag name.
> 3. Optionally, one or more attributes, each of which must be preceded by one or more space characters.
> 4. Optionally, one or more space characters.
> 5. Optionally, a "/" character, which may be present only if the element is a void element.
> 6. A ">" character.

The `meta` is a *void* element and hence the part #5 would apply with a caveat that "***optionally**, a `/` character, which **may** be present...*"

```
<meta ... />
```

And so, you ***may*** omit the part #5 i.e. the closing "/", and hence this is also valid:

```
<meta ... >
```

Further down the spec says:

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified
> for void elements.

To summarize, end tag is not required. Self closing is not required. It will not hurt if end tag or self-close is present.

.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you use **HTML5** or **XHTML5** syntax. In **XHTML5** it is required and the parser will freak out if you don't use `/` when closing tag. Generaly all **XML** elements must have closing tag.

Try this snippet of code in [Validator.nu](https://validator.nu/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Try to remove `/` from `meta charset` and observe the result. Don't forget to set correct preset for `XHTML5`.

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at Mozilla's documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta), as well as from what I've observed in general, you just *don't close the tag.*

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The above is valid HTML5.  There's no reason to include any sort of close tag or anything resembling a closing tag on it.