# How I do replace <br></br> and remove href attribute at the same time?

Tags: javascript, dom, whmcs

I am using WHMCS (owned licensed without branding), however I want to change the layout a bit. The part I want to change is IONcube encoded, so I have to rely on Javascript (or DOM even?) to make those changes.

The ID name is: `ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-0`
It ranges from 0 to whatever the amount of products the customer has.

From that ID I want to change the displayed `<br></br>` into `{$LANG.gekoppeldaan}`

Secondly; I also want to remove the href tag from that same ID, since we don't use those pages it's pointing to.

I already had some success with replacing the `<br></br>` by using:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-0 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-1 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-2 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-3 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-4 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-5 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-6 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-7 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-8 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-9 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
   $('#ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-10 br').replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
});
</script>
```

I somehow doubt this is a "clean" way to do this and if a customer has over 100 products, I have to create 100 of those lines. Which isn't very clean.

I haven't tried removing the href tag, simply because I don't know how.

So my question is, can someone provide some kind of clean code which replaces all

```
<br></br>
```

with `{$LANG.gekoppeldaan}` for all current and upcoming ID's called `ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-0` and at the same time removes the href tag/url from it.

As mentioned above the ID `ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-0` increases by one for every product the customer has. So instead of adding these manually, there must be an automatic way, right? Maybe through javascript and/or DOM.

I hope I was clear enough.

//update

Thanks to Andreas (comment) and Axel I managed to get it working! Many thanks.

I used this:

```
<script>
$('[id^="ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-"] br').replaceWith(" {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ");
$('[id^="ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-"]').removeAttr('href');
</script>
```

Comment: I will help you, please add how before 2 tags with #ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-X are looking and what should be the result.

Comment: Use the "attribute value starts with" selector `^=` -> `$("[id^=ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-]" br)` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u7pfrfz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional, empty class to all of these entries:

```
<... id="ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-0" 
           class="ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services" .... />
```

work with jQuery each iterator:

```
$('.ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services br').each(function(index, elem) {

      $(elem).replaceWith(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
      $(elem).removeAttr('href');

};
```

Mind the `.Client...`selector which will find all elements of that class, regardless how many that are

Answer (score 1):

I suppose u have anchors..

```js
$( "a[id*='ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-']" ).each( function( index, element ){
    $(element).prepend(' {$LANG.gekoppeldaan} ');
    var kiddos = $(element).children("br");
    if (kiddos != undefined)
      {
          kiddos[0].remove();
          if (kiddos.length > 1)
          kiddos[1].remove();
       }
    $(element).removeAttr('href');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a id="ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-1" href="#">
        <br>
        </br>
        <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhud2eyWOjWo44aQhYedOM7GCl4rUbNxx_UpGtb2x_t04DU9qI" width=650px" />
    </a>
    <a id="ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-2"  href="#">
        <br>
        </br>
         <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhud2eyWOjWo44aQhYedOM7GCl4rUbNxx_UpGtb2x_t04DU9qI" width=650px" />
    </a>
    <a id="ClientAreaHomePagePanels-Active_Products_Services-3"  href="#">
        </br>
        <br>
          <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhud2eyWOjWo44aQhYedOM7GCl4rUbNxx_UpGtb2x_t04DU9qI" width=650px" />
    </a>
```

Add more details how you want to do it, you will face some problems if you are using underscore or some dependency injections.

Comment: This removes everything? Not just the < br>< /br>? The only things it's now showing is the language text variable.

Comment: ok I will fix it, but I asked you to show me original html and desired result, btw <br></ br> check w3c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br is incorect

Comment: Yeah I know it's not w3c, but as mentioned this is created by WHMCS, not by me! Also it's encoded in IonCube, so I cannot change it obviously.