# Adding a line break in an array of text

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 `Arrays` of `TextList` and everytime a button is pressed, the text will appear one after another. However, The next text appears beside the previous text. I would like the next text to appear below instead. I tried using `<html>` and `<p>` but instead they appear with the text. How do i make the text to appear below instead of beside each other?
This is my sample of code.

```
    textList.add("<html> Testing");
    textList.add("<p> asdasdssss<p>ssssssssssssa<p>dssad");
    textList.add("\n lmaoasdasasd" + "</html>");


    JLabel hint = new JLabel("");
    hint.setBounds(29, 21, 395, 134);
    panel.add(hint);


    JButton btnHint = new JButton("hint");
    btnHint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            hint.setText(hint.getText() + "\n" + textList.get(textIndex++));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use ``\r\n`` instead of ``\n`` or format the thing using html tags..

Comment: Incrementing `textIndex` without checking it will throw IndexOutOfBounds eventually

Comment: yep it will throw an error after the 3rd click, however right now the problem is i tried using <html>, <p>, \n, <br> tags in my textList strings but they appear with the string instead.

Answer (score -1):

Html tag < p> requires a closing <\p> try using tag < br> which does not require closing tag. This tag means "break" which means new line. Use this great [HTML tutrial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) to learn HTML "on the fly"

Comment: "<br> which does not require closing tag" is a horrible advice. Every tag needs to be closed, use ``<br />`` instead.

Comment: Actually according to the best rated answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br tag <br> is completely valid. you voted me down unfarely

Comment: Also, to even further prove my point look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp