# Displaying List of items in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Greetings, I ran into an issue on how to display items from my list. I have looked online but the only code was in c# with `console.writeline` command. I also tried this:

```
Response.Write(Convert.ToString(orderList[i]) + "<br \\");
```

and

```
lblOrder.Text = Convert.ToString(orderList[i]);
```

however it doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
    if(getOrangeTotal != 0) {
        orderList.Add(getOrangeTotal);
    }
    if (getBreadTotal != 0) { 

        orderList.Add(getBreadTotal);
    }

    sizeOfList = orderList.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfList; i++)
    {
        //lblOrder.Text = Convert.ToString(orderList[i]);
        //Response.Write(Convert.ToString(orderList[i]) + "<br \\");
    }
```

Explanation: 
The code gets values from Session Variables from previous page and I want to display values that don't have value of 0 in them.

Comment: what is this `Response.Write(Convert.ToString(orderList[i]) + "<br \\");` why do you have double back slashes..? inside of double quotes and html tags , the single back slash is not seen as a return character..

Comment: @MethodMan this is a web-based application, i want to display all of the content from the list in a list going down.

Comment: you mean a `dropdownlist`?

Comment: I would highly suggest that you do a google search on the following `C# stackoverflow populating a dropdownlist from database` or do the same search on how to `Bind List<T> to a dropdownlist` also read up on `PostBacks` and understand the life cycle of an `ASP.NET WebPage.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you appear to be displaying (or attempting to display) an entire list within a single control (a label) by delimiting the items with `<BR>` tags. That is a pretty bizarre way to go about it. It is no wonder you are fighting the technology.

Generally speaking, if you have a list of items to display, you would use something like a [Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) control (on web forms) or a simple `foreach` (in MVC). Or you could bind the items to a [`DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want the user to be able to choose one.

If you truly know what you are doing and want to put everything into one controls's `Text` property, you could use a little LINQ:

```
litFoo.Text = string.Join
              (
                  "<br>", 
                  list.Select( a => a.ToString() )
              );
```

Note that `litFoo` in this example is a Literal which won't have the same sort of escaping issues as a Label control.

BTW `<BR>` is a self closing entity so you [don't need to worry about any slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br).