# Mermaid diagram line break

Tags: r, line-breaks, diagram, sequence-diagram, mermaid

I cannot find how to insert a line break in long titles inside nodes. For example:

```
library(DiagrammeR) 
mermaid("
graph TB
     A[GE Solution]-->C{ }
     B[GA Solution]-->C{ } 
     C{ }-->D[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]
     D[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]-->E[Homogenisation at 10000 r/min]
     E[Homogenisation at 10000 r/min]-->F(Stir 10 min 450 r/min Complex coacervation)
      ")
```

Note node `F` is too long. How to I make it into sth like..?

```
|Stir 10 min 450 r/min|
|Complex coacervation |
```

Note `\n` doesn't work.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It appears you can use [`<br>`](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/examples.html#larger-flowchart-with-some-styling) instead:

```
mermaid("
graph TB
        A[GE Solution]-->C{ }
        B[GA Solution]-->C{ } 
        C{ }-->D[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]
        D[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]-->E[Homogenisation at 10000 r/min]
        E[Homogenisation at 10000 r/min]-->F(Stir 10 min 450 r/min <br> Complex  coacervation)
        ")
```

[image]

Comment: On the nail! I couldn't find this in the instructions. thnx

Comment: Also when saving SVG and opening in a browser it is complaining about missing `<br>` close tag, `<br/>` looks to be more appropriate but it's saved as `<br>` anyways maybe it's a mermaid bug

Comment: @Aleksei Good call out, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Comment: how about mermaid's ER diagrams' comment

Answer (score 4):

Another answer that appears to work just fine is to use `\n` rather than `<br>`.

Comment: It doesn't work. Either present an example as how you are using it or share a link explaining your answer in detail.

Comment: `\n` does not work at `participant` in flowcharts. `<br>` works though.

Comment: I am using Mermaid via [Markdown Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk) (a Chrome Extension), neither work to produce line break. But it works when I push it to GitHub. Perhaps in my case is implementation in the extension.

Comment: Neither \n nor <br> nor <br/> work when I create the diagram using mermaid cli. It <br> works with Intellij Markdown viewer though.