# How can I set newline behavior for htmleditorkit

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, htmleditorkit

I have a JEditorPane set to edit html input and I would like to change the newline behavior so that when I go to a new line it inserts `<\br>` instead of surrounding the text in `<p></p>`. At the moment I have the following.

```
newSignatureScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
newSignatureEditorPane = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();
newSignatureEditorPane.setContentType("text/html"); // NOI18N
newSignatureEditorPane.setDocument(new HTMLDocument());
newSignatureEditorPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
newSignatureScrollPane.setViewportView(newSignatureEditorPane);
```

This results in the following when I do a `newSignatureEditorPane.getText()` in my saveChangesButtonAction:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p style="margin-top: 0">
  Line 1
</p>
<p style="margin-top: 0">
  Line 2
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want <\br>? Maybe you meant <br> or <br/> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946446/6358346

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's `<br/>`.  Google uses `<div></div>`, so I guess that would be good too.

Comment: I still have not found a solution to this issue.  I've seen bug reports, so I'm surprised it hasn't been fixed by now.