# Beginner: Multiple Choice Quiz

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm a **Beginner**. I'm making a Multiple Choice Quiz. I want the results from **ALL** my Buttons to display in my Label when the user Submits their answers. **How do I do this?**

- (2 Questions) 4 Radio Buttons
- 1 DropDown (ID="DropDownList1")
- 1 CheckBox (ID="CheckBoxList1")
- 1 FeedBack/ShortAnswer TextBox
- Submit Button
- Results Label

Basically I want it to display like this:

> **Results:**
>
> You answered 2 questions correctly
>
> - Question 1 is Correct
> - Question 2 is Incorrect. The correct answer is True.
> - Question 3 is Correct
>
> I like apples because they are good for your health.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Project4
{
    public partial class Project4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void ClickHereForMore_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://my.sunysuffolk.edu/web/home-community/activities-information");
        }


        protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            if (RadioButtonTrue.Checked)
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Question 1 is Correct";
            }
            else if (RadioButtonFalse.Checked)
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Question 1 is False. Correct answer is True.";
            }
            if (RadioButtonYes.Checked)
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Question 2 is Correct";
            }
            else if (RadioButtonNo.Checked)
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Question 2 is False. Correct answer is True.";
            }





        }

        protected void FeedBack_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblResults.Text = FeedBack.Text;

        }


    }
}
```

One of my problems right now is that the RadioButton is displaying only the Results of Question 2. I think I know why, but I don't know how to fix it so that it will display both Question 1 and 2 answers. I can only imagine this issue becoming bigger when I try to do the same for the other buttons. Also the feedback text isn't displaying.

Comment: Hint: `+=` adds to the text already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `lblResults.Text = "Question 2 is Correct";` you need to append the text. As it stands you are replacing it.

Use the following instead, note `+=` to append the string:

```
if (RadioButtonYes.Checked)
{
   lblResults.Text += "<br>Question 2 is Correct";
}
else if (RadioButtonNo.Checked)
{
   lblResults.Text += "<br>Question 2 is False. Correct answer is True.";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the newline character `\n`

Comment: For the new line i needed to use  "<br />"

Comment: `<br>` is the preferred choice for HTML5 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946446/4665 . However `<br />` is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for that, and the link was helpful.