# Does document.write("</br>") produce valid html and if so why?

Tags: javascript

`document.write("</br>");` was written on the board by our teacher as an example for how to make a new line with javascript. In my experience as a web developer I have never seen this slash in front of br. But when I test it with chrome web development tools it works and it simply converts `</br>` to `<br>`. Yet I do not understand why.

Comment: Browsers know people make misteaks

Comment: `<br/>` is valid, but `</br>` is not

Comment: `<br>` would actually be invalid too.

Comment: I believe you mean new line with html. Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br) is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write("</br>");` does *not* produces valid HTML.

*However* it is frequent to observe browser-side HTML error correction mechanisms. In the wild, most small invalid HTML errors get corrrected and valid HTML ends up in the DOM: closing tags at the end of a file that can be deduced from the rest of the content, `<br/>` or `<br></br>` instead of `<br>`, `<input ... />` instead of `<input ... >`, and so on.

Different browsers offer different error correction mechanisms and they don't follow any particular standard so it's always good to avoid relying on them.