# looking for a right counterclockwise arrow

Tags: html, mathjax

I am rewriting this question as it was closed because recommending books or sites are not allowed. So please don't recommend books or sites. :)

I have an online course that contains mathematical equations and formulas. My instructor gives me the equations and formulas in image form or using Microsoft Word. I translate convert these in HTML using Mathjax. However, I came upon an illustration (see below) wherein a fraction, there is a counterclockwise arrow on the leftside coming from the numerator to the denominator. On the right side of the fraction is another arrow. This time it is a right counterclockwise arrow coming from the denominator to the numerator.

[image: this is a sample equation. On the leftside of the fraction is a left counterclockwise arrow. On the rightside of the fraction is a right counterclockwise arrow.]

The left arrow, I was able to find in HTML entities, but somehow I could not find one for the rightside. I went through the HTML entities symbols and search in Mathjax, but I could not find that arrow. This is my last stop to see if anyone knows if such an arrow exist in either HTML entities or in Mathjax. I hope to avoid using an image for this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here or nowhere: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

Comment: You could always reverse the arrow direction with css if you really need to

Comment: somehow that never occured to me to use css. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here or nowhere: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

```css
.mirror{
    display: inline-block; 
   transform: rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<span>⤸</span> RIGHT-SIDE ARC CLOCKWISE ARROW  <br/>
<span>⤹</span> LEFT-SIDE ARC ANTICLOCKWISE ARROW   <br/>
<hr/>
<span class="mirror">⤸</span> RIGHT-SIDE ARC CLOCKWISE ARROW transformed <br/>
<span class="mirror">⤹</span> LEFT-SIDE ARC ANTICLOCKWISE ARROW transformed  <br/>
```

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob not entirely true. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br I prefer it WITH the end slash because I edit XML and XHMTL a lot

Comment: The question is tagged HTML. In any case, in HTML, that closing slash has no meaning, does nothing, and browsers are instructed to ignore it, making it pointless and useless.

Comment: Please find something important to complain about. It does no harm anywhere but a lack of / DOES harm in certain situation and OP did not tag it xhtml but who knows how it behaves in mathml!