# How to get my table data in a row without tables

Tags: php

I have a database and I am trying to display data from the table all in one box.

I am not sure if there is another way besides tables but I am trying to do something like this.

I am using roblox as an example.

Example:
[image: Example]

Right now this is my code for the table.

```
                    <div class="row2">
  <div class="column">
  <?php
                    include_once("includes/config.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM communities";  
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 1) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<hr />';
                echo '<table>';
                echo '<tr><td>Name: </td><td>'.$row["name"].'</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Discription:</td><td>'.$row["description"].'</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td></td><td><img src="'.$row["logo"].'" width="100px" /></td></tr>';
                echo '</table>';
                echo '<button name="button">Join</button>';
                echo '<hr />';
            }
        }       
                ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is `<hr />`?

Comment: Its to make a line

Comment: To make a horizontal rule we use <hr> not <hr />

Comment: Look I am new to coding and just looking for some help

Comment: @DevinHenrickson Your code creates a new table for every row from the database. Is this intentional?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Ohh! ok thanks.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I do not know what I am doing. The code is something I was just trying to do to help me display the data it was supposed to display. Now I am trying to make it into boxes like roblox and display the data like that. Where every new row is a new box or something like that/

Comment: @Kunal Raut - hr is analog to br (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br) Yes, it is possible to write <hr />. The slash is not needed but it is no fault and it was rude to ask this question and not help Devin with his problem ...

Devin Henrickson: You can change each table into a DIV-construct. But what is your concrete question and where are you stuck?

Comment: @DevinHenrickson Sounds like you are looking for a CSS framework.

Comment: @Melvin What I am stuck on is the ability to make the data appear horizontally. On my test site you can see how the data is located. I want it like that but appears horizontally. 
So instead of it going down, I want it to progress to the side.
http://testingsite1.devinhenrickson.com/

Comment: @Devin Henrickson OK. If you want to add several items horizontally you need something to scroll the items horizontal or you make sure the items can't "grow" out on the right side of your browser. It's possible to add a certain amount of items, then add a line-break and start the next item-line. Or you have something with a slider which can grow indefinitly to the right. (simplest form is the iframe)

Comment: @Melvin I think your correct with that about CSS framework. Davin, try with CSS framework like Bootstrap. colomn and row class may be help you.