# How can I align the checkboxes and text vertically?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, alignment, vertical-alignment

I want the checkboxes to be parallel to each other and the text to be aligned the same.
This is what i have (i'm new to this):

```html
<input type="checkbox" name=”liste1” value="1">This is Example1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name=”liste1” value="2">Example2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name=”liste1” value="3">Example123456<br>
<input type="checkbox" name=”liste1”` value="4">Option4<br>
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vaLV.png)

Comment: Start by closing your tags and using valid quotation marks.

Comment: I changed the quotation marks, but which tags do you mean?

Comment: Do you want the checkbox to be align the same on the first visual column and the text to be centered aside according to the longest one ? Something alike : https://jsfiddle.net/qw6gvjms/ ? @iliasKarim

Comment: No the question asks for vertical not horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 1):

When a parent element is allowed to `display: flex`, each child element will be aligned vertically when the `align-item: center` is declared

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3px;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="liste1" name="liste1" value="1">
   <label for="liste1"> Option 1</label>
</div>
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="liste2" name="liste2" value="2">
   <label for="liste2"> Option 2</label>
</div>
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="liste3" name="liste3" value="3">
   <label for="liste3"> Option 3</label>
</div>
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="liste4" name="liste4" value="4">
   <label for="liste4"> Option 4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, we'll correct the original version of the code:

- `”` is not a valid quote to use in HTML, you should use either `"` or `'`
- If an HTML tag doesn't have a closing tag (e.g. `<p>content</p>`) then it is referred to as self-closing, and should have a slash before the closing angle bracket, like this: `<input />`

This gives us:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="liste1" value="1" />This is Example1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="liste1" value="2" />Example2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="liste1" value="3" />Example123456<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="liste1" value="4" />Option4<br />
```

This is enough to get it to look right, however generally if you want to show text next to a checkbox, you want it to be clickable and affect the checkbox. The simplest way to do this is to wrap the input and it's label text inside a `<label>` element, like so:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

input,
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="liste1" value="1" />
  <span>This is Example1</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="liste1" value="2" />
  <span>Example2</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="liste1" value="3" />
  <span>Example123456</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="liste1" value="4" />
  <span>Option4</span>
</label>
```

(I also used a small CSS rule instead of the `<br />` tag, as it's generally preferable to use CSS for layout)

Comment: Self closing tags do not **need** to have a slash before the closing bracket, this is only the case when using XHTML. (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946446/9288348)

Comment: @Jeremy They don't require a closing slash for technical reasons anymore, but it is still often considered good practice for readability and is a useful habit if working in frontend libraries that allow self-closing empty non-void elements (E.g. React's JSX)

Answer (score 0):

your picture says column but your question says row.  Which one do you want?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap: 13px;
  align-items: center
}

#container2 {
  display: flex;
  margin-top:20vw;
  
  gap: 83px;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="liste1" name="liste1" value="1">
    <label for="liste1"> Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="liste2" name="liste2" value="2">
    <label for="liste2"> Option 2 xxx</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="liste3" name="liste3" value="3">
    <label for="liste3"> Option 3 xxx xxx</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="liste4" name="liste4" value="4">
    <label for="liste4"> Option 4 xxx</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='container2'>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="liste1" name="liste1" value="1">
    <label for="liste1"> Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="liste2" name="liste2" value="2">
    <label for="liste2"> Option 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="liste3" name="liste3" value="3">
    <label for="liste3"> Option 3</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="liste4" name="liste4" value="4">
    <label for="liste4"> Option 4</label>
  </div>
</div>
```