# <!DOCTYPE html> vs <!doctype html> and <meta charset="utf-8"> vs <meta charset="utf-8" />

Tags: html, utf-8

Document Type Declaration

`<!DOCTYPE html>` vs `<!doctype html>`

Capital letter DOCTYPE declaration or small letter doctype declaration which one is authentic?

Character encoding meta tag

Same type of 3 character encoding meta tags

1. `<meta charset="utf-8">` non-slash version
2. `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` slash version
3. `<meta charset="utf-8" />` a single white space followed by slash.

Which one is authentic?

Comment: the `/>` is a relic of XML display (XHTML), and is not ***required*** with HTML5. Browsers are all flexible enough to realise this so this coding style is entirely optional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML 5: Is it <br>, <br/>, or <br />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br)

Answer (score 0):

To be sincere all are the same.
**It depends on your preference**
You can choose to use any of them.