# Get innerText and split by <br>

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

Below is a minimal example of some HTML for which I am trying to extract the text Content. My desired outcome is the array `['keep1', 'keep2', 'keep3', 'keep4', 'keep5']`, so I am dropping anything that is a child element of the div, then splitting the div's text into an array on the `<br />` tags.

Usually I would use `.innerText` on the div which helpfully gets all the text and drops child elements, but as far as I am aware is not suitable in this case because then I lose the `<br />` tags that I need for splitting into an array. Below is the best I could come up with, but doesn't handle cases where child elements are not surrounded by `<br />`. Is there any better way to do this?

```js
const text = document
  .querySelector("div")
  .innerHTML.split("<br>")
  .map(e => e.trim())
  .filter(e => e[0] != "<" && e != "");
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div>
  <br /> keep1 <br /> keep2
  <span>drop</span> keep3
  <br /> keep4
  <br />
  <h4>drop2</h4>
  <br />keep5
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is as below:

```js
// we use the spread syntax inside of an Array-literal to convert the
// iterable result of document.querySelector().childNodes into an
// Array:
const text = [...
  // here we retrieve the first/only <div> element from the document
  // and return the live NodeList of all its child-nodes:
  document.querySelector('div').childNodes
  // we then use Array.prototype.filter() to filter the returned collection:
].filter(
  // we use an Arrow function to test each node passed to the
  // Array.prototype.filter() method ('node' is a reference to the current
  // node of the Array of nodes;
  // node.nodeType: we first test that the node has a nodeType,
  // we then assess if the node is a textNode (the nodeType of a text-node
  // is 3),
  // finally - to prevent empty array-element-values - we check that
  // the length of the nodeValue (the text-content of the text-node) once
  // leading and trailing white-space is removed has a length greater
  // than zero:
  (node) => node.nodeType && node.nodeType === 3 && node.nodeValue.trim().length > 0
  // we then use Array.prototype.map() to return a new Array based on the existing
  // Array of text-nodes:
).map(
  // again we pass the array-element into the function,
  // and here we trim the leading/trailing white-space of the node's value,
  // by passing the string to String.prototype.trim():
  (node) => node.nodeValue.trim()
);

console.log(text); // ["keep1","keep2","keep3","keep4","keep5"]
```

```html
<div>
  <br /> keep1 <br /> keep2
  <span>drop</span> keep3
  <br /> keep4
  <br />
  <h4>drop2</h4>
  <br />keep5
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b0ehayLt/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes).
- [`node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).
- [`node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Answer (score 2):

In the order of operations, it's easier to replace the line breaks with `<br>` tags first using `/\n/g`, then split the result. Once we've taken care of the only html elements we care about (`<br>`), we can strip out the rest using the regex `/\<(.*)\>/g`

It was actually a surprise to me that `<br />` gets 'normalized to `<br>` when the tags are parsed - but as [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946446/1772933) states, `<br />` is XHTML and the browser parses everything to HTML `<br>`

```js
const text = document
  .querySelector("div")
  .innerHTML.replace(/\n/g,"<br>") // replace all line breaks with `<br>`
  .split("<br>")
  .map(e => e.replace(/\<(.*)\>/g,'').trim()) // we clean and trim the element from any html tags
  .filter(e=>e) // this cleans out the empty array elements
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div>
  <br /> keep1 <br /> keep2
  <span>drop</span> keep3
  <br /> keep4
  <br />
  <h4>drop2</h4>
  <br />keep5
</div>
```