# How to use br tag in html

Tags: html

My problem is that I don't really know how to use the br tag in HTML?
In our class test, we had to find all the problems in an HTML script, and I thought that < /br> was wrong.
Which of these are HTML conform, because I think 1 and 2 are:

1. < br>
2. < br />
3. < /br>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML 5: Is it <br>, <br/>, or <br />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br)

Answer (score 0):

- `<br>` will do the trick.
- you can also do `<br/>`. It is a self closing tag.
- but you can only use `</br>` like this `<br></br>` in XHTML only. It will not work with HTML5.

So I'd say go with `<br>` or `<br/>`

Comment: thank you. Now I can proof my teacher that he was wrong with closing the br tag.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider upvoting if I am of any help. You can find a detailed overview here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br