# Reuse HTML with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I want to resuse a part of the HTML along with the associated css, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Everything has to do with jQuery.

Comment: @BoltClock: You can leverage jQuery templates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create client side templates such jQuery templates or underscore templates which can reuse your HTML layout.

Here's a over-simplified example of dynamically generated `ul` which generates a list of customer's firstname given a data object (`d`):

```
<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/html">
        <ul>
        <#
            for(var i=0; i < d.length; i++)     
            {      
               var cust = d[i]; 
        #>
                   <li id="Customer_<#= i.toString() #>">
                        <#= cust.FirstName #> 
                   </li>
        <# 
            }
        #>
        </ul>
</script>
```

Detailed post here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/05/03/using-jquery-with-client-side-data-binding-templates.aspx

Answer (score 8):

User a server-side language like PHP to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to create a sort of template right? you may have to use a server-side language like PHP to do it.

You may need to create some files like: header.php, body.php and footer.php

and an index.php file would work like this:

```
<?php
     require "header.php";
     require "body.php";
     require "footer.php";
¿>
```

Comment: ha! where did php come into the mix?

Answer (score 2):

HTML cannot be "reused".

An HTML structure can be reused, but as HTML informs the relationships between bits of text, and text varies from page to page, the HTML *itself* cannot be reused.

**However:** If you write HTML in a fairly consistent manner, and keep your CSS relatively free of special cases and crazy contortions in order to implement visuals (that might not be a good idea in the first place, even), a lot of the time you can simply `@import` the style sheet.

A good idea for doing this is to separate your CSS into two files; e.g. layout.css and style.css.

layout.css would contain the general layout of the page; ".menu goes to the right", "h3 is 24px bold", "p has a 5em margin on the right" sort of stuff.

style.css would contain the color scheme, the image replacement code as relevant, and generally specific stuff, and start by `@import`ing structure.css.

This way, if you want to reuse the general layout, you can do so quickly and effortlessly without getting a lot of baggage. The SE sites are an example of a kind of site that uses *the fundamental aspects of this approach*, even if they don't do it exactly that way.

**Note:** I don't see how this question relates to JavaScript, but I'll try to answer that bit as well:

When you use JavaScript or jQuery; any CSS that applies to elements you are `$.clone()`ing or similar will also apply to wherever you put it in next.

Answer (score 1):

Clone it with jQuery if you could use it:

```
$('#parent .child').clone().appendTo('#parent');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jQuery's clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

From the jQuery site:

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes. When used in conjunction
>   with one of the insertion methods, .clone() is a convenient way to
>   duplicate elements on a page.

Answer (score 0):

View the source of the webpage:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  => Select All

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  => Copy

Open a text editor or IDE if you have not already:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> => Paste

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>  => Save (to a .html extension)

Comment: -1, partially for glibness, partially for this being the wrong approach to basically anything.

Comment: `Ctrl + V`, not `P` - but I admire your speed.

Comment: @Williham -- i typed a little fast ^_^

Comment: @Renesis: You can't beat [answering a question in 24 seconds while doing a test in a computer lab.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/browsers-think-div-not-ending/5455770#5455770)

Comment: @Neal: I'm serious - mouse over the timestamps :P

Comment: @Boltclock -- i looked at your original answer -- twas muuuch shorter :-P

Comment: @Neal: That's my little "secret" ;)

Comment: Rule of thumb: Copy-pasting is evil.

Answer (score 0):

If you're purely using HTML and CSS, that's not possible. If you use some JavaScript or other server-side programming, then you can store the HTML in a variable and echo it back later.